# Error when using any Android Design Support Library Elements

Tags: android, android-support-library, android-design-library

Error inflating anything from the design support library

**xml**

```
<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

**build.gradle**

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:22.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:22.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v13:22.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.0'
```

**project build.gradle**

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.2.3'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
}
```

**Error:**

```
Binary XML file line #115: Error inflating class
android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
```

My Sdk Manager everything is up to date.
[image: SDK Manager]

Comment: is error in rendreng  or in logcat

Comment: in logcat when trying to render

Comment: it,s problem in andriod studio latest update ... it should be fixed soon

Comment: @MaherIsmaail I have a sample project running the design support library just fine with the same config as this project. Are you sure it's a Studio problem?

Comment: did you try to compile app with api 21  ..

Answer (score 27, accepted):

In addition to Emmanuel's answer you could be facing the following problem.

It seems like the design library components need a style which is based on an AppCompat Theme. So try to use "Theme.AppCompat.[...]" as a parent in your style.xml.

Example:

```
<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Base.AppTheme">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
</style>

<style name="Base.AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="android:colorPrimary">@color/primary</item>
    <item name="android:colorPrimaryDark">@color/primary_dark</item>
    <item name="android:colorAccent">@color/accent</item>
</style>
```

Then add the following to your build.gradle as well:

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.0'
```

Additionally you should update the following lines in your gradle as well:

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.2.3'
compileSdkVersion 22
buildToolsVersion '22.0.1'
targetSdkVersion 22
```

Comment: This worked. I needed to change the parent of my AppTheme. Thanks!

Comment: That also worked for me, but then my `Toolbar` disappears. Is there a way to keep `Theme.Materia`l and to have `NavigationView`?

Comment: Make sure class extends the AppCompatActivity and not just Activity.

`import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;

public class MyActivity extends AppCompatActivity { 
[...]`

Comment: Thank you, this helped me too

Comment: it worked for me to just change the theme of the FAB to 'app:theme="@style/Base.Theme.AppCompat.Light'

Answer (score 11):

Update Support Library on SDK Manager in Extras > Android Support Repository and Android Support Library, that works for me ;)

and dont forget to add the compile 'com.android.support:design:22.2.0' on app.gradle and sync

Answer (score 5):

In my case the same crash while using **android.support.design.widget.NavigationView** was solved by adding **app:itemTextColor** attribute to the layout xml:

```
    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/navigation"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header"
        app:itemTextColor="?android:textColorPrimary"
        app:menu="@menu/drawer"/>
```

Answer (score 3):

Be aware that even if you are using the `FloatingActionButton` widget that is in the Design Support library, you still have to use `srcCompat` to reference your icon, if you want the FAB to work on older devices.

```
<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_keyboard_arrow_right_black_24dp"
    ... />
```

Answer (score 0):

One thing to double-check is that you have applied your theme correctly in your AndroidManifest.xml file. In my case, I had omitted the android:theme attribute. E.g:

```
<application ... android:theme="@style/Your.Theme.Here" ... >
```