# Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.NavigationView

Tags: android, android-support-library, androiddesignsupport

I followed a tutorial of new component [NavigationView](https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/Fragment-Navigation-Drawer) in Support Design Library and can't get through this error message :

```
Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
```

I tried every workaround here

[Error when using any Android Design Support Library Elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30547323/error-when-using-any-android-design-support-library-elements)

but error message still exists.

#### xml

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true" >
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <include layout="@layout/toolbar" android:id="@+id/mainToolBar" />

    <fragment android:name="com.ais.cherry.fragment.LoginFragment"
        android:id="@+id/loginFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@id/mainToolBar" />
    <fragment     android:name="com.ais.cherry.fragment.WaterFallFragment"
        android:id="@+id/mainFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@id/mainToolBar" />
    <fragment android:name="com.ais.cherry.fragment.SearchFragment"
        android:id="@+id/searchFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@id/mainToolBar" />
    <fragment android:name="com.ais.cherry.fragment.ChatMainFragment"
        android:id="@+id/chatMainFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@id/mainToolBar" />
    <fragment android:name="com.ais.cherry.fragment.ProfileFragment"
        android:id="@+id/profileFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@id/mainToolBar" />


    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="240dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:background="@android:color/white"
        app:itemTextColor="#212121"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/drawer_header"
        app:menu="@menu/drawer" />
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

#### build.gradle

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.+'
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.2.3'
    }
}

compileSdkVersion 22
buildToolsVersion "22.0.1"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.ais.cherry"
    minSdkVersion 16
    targetSdkVersion 22      
    multiDexEnabled true
    renderscriptTargetApi 22
    renderscriptSupportModeEnabled true

}
dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:22.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:22.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:22.2.0'
}
```

#### Project build.gradle

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.2.3'
    }
}
```

#### styles.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="AppTheme.Base">

</style>

<style name="AppTheme.Base" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="android:windowActionBarOverlay">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowActionModeOverlay">true</item>
    <item name="android:actionModeStyle">@style/AppTheme.ActionModeStyle</item>
    <item name="android:windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <!-- Support library compatibility -->
    <item name="windowActionBarOverlay">true</item>

    <!-- ActionBar color -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">#E91E63</item>
    <!-- Status bar color -->
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">#C2185B</item>
    <!-- Window color -->
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/white</item>
    <!-- ActionBar title text -->
    <item name="android:titleTextStyle">@style/AppTheme.MyActionBarTitleText</item>

    <item name="colorAccent">#9E9E9E</item>

    <item name="drawerArrowStyle">@style/AppTheme.MyDrawerArrowStyle</item>

    <!-- color for actionMenu-->
    <item name="actionMenuTextColor">#FFFFFF</item>
    <item name="android:actionMenuTextColor">#FFFFFF</item>
    <!-- android:textColorSecondary is the color of the menu
   overflow icon (three vertical dots) -->
    <item name="android:textColorPrimary">#212121</item>
    <item name="android:textColorSecondary">#FFFFFF</item>
    <!--Navigation bar color-->
    <item name="android:navigationBarColor">#E91E63</item>
    <!--Status bar color-->
    <item name="android:statusBarColor">#C2185B</item>
</style>
```

Any help would be appreciated!

### Edit -- add @menu/drawer & @menu/drawer_header & stacktrace

#### drawer.xml

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <group android:checkableBehavior="single">
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_first_fragment"
            android:icon="@drawable/home_view"
            android:checked="true"
            android:title="@string/main"/>
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_second_fragment"
            android:icon="@drawable/comment_view"
            android:title="@string/chat"/>
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_third_fragment"
            android:icon="@drawable/user_view"
            android:title="@string/profile"/>
        <item android:title="@string/search">
            <menu>
                <item
                    android:title="@string/clothes"/>
                <item
                    android:title="@string/pants"/>
            </menu>
        </item>
    </group>
</menu>
```

#### drawer_header.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="192dp"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimaryDark"
    android:padding="16dp"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark"
    android:gravity="bottom">
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/title"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Body1"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

#### StackTrace (only part of them)

It thrown out three exceptions as below : all points out that the problems is  caused by the line of "setContentView(layout)" at  in layout.xml.

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity  ComponentInfo{com.ais.cherry/com.ais.cherry.activity.FirstActivity}:    android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #32: Error inflating    class android.support.design.widget.NavigationView

Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #32: Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.NavigationView

Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException

Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x0
```

Comment: Can you also post the xml `@layout/drawer_header` and xml `@menu/drawer`?

Comment: Also, please post the entire stack trace.

Comment: Well, it can't find one of your resources. I do not know which, though.

Comment: I faced this because I refactored some code. Basically I refactored a variable called parent to parentFragment to be more accurate and android studio made the change in styles.xml too. Had to fix the style back to parent=“<whatever-base-class>” and it worked again.

Answer (score 83, accepted):

Actually it is not the matter of the `primarycolortext`, upgrading or downgrading the dependencies.This problem will likely occur when the version of your `appcompat` library and design support library doesn't match.

Example of matching condition

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1' // appcompat library
compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.1'       //design support library
```

Comment: Can you explain me how to detect this problem for a newbie like me plz :)

Comment: If you always declare a variable for things like this in your app/build.gradle you prevent yourself from forgetting to change, as in:
`def supportVersion = '25.1.0'
compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:$supportVersion"
compile "com.android.support:design:$supportVersion"`

Comment: both the libraries uses by me are same but still getting same error. Check below code   compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.4.0'

Comment: I should use `support of version 26`. I'm using `'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'`.

Is `26.1.0` correct?

Comment: Error faced on Gradle 4.1 with compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion '26.0.2' and  compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.0.0'       
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.0.0'

Solved making below changes
 compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:25.0.0'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.0.0'

Comment: if you have only `dimen.xml(v21)`, your app will crash on android version 4 & less. Create another dimens.xml, copy all attributes from dimens.xml(v21) to newly created dimens.xml. Error Fixed.

Answer (score 45):

I had similar error.
When i use

```
<style name="AppTheme.Base" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">

    <item name="colorPrimary">#673AB7</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">#512DA8</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">#00BCD4</item>
    <item name="android:textColorPrimary">#212121</item>
    <item name="android:textColorSecondary">#727272</item>

</style>
```

works for me when i remove the android:textColorPrimary and android:textColorSecondary theme items.

```
<style name="AppTheme.Base" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">

    <item name="colorPrimary">#673AB7</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">#512DA8</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">#00BCD4</item>

</style>
```

Try working with a very simple App theme to start off with.

EDIT:

This [tutorial](http://www.sitepoint.com/material-design-android-design-support-library/) will help.
My understanding is that using "android:textColorPrimary" requires minimum api level 21. Using the same tag without "android:" uses the design support library. Any support library widget will try to find the "textColorPrimary" item instead of "android:textColorPrimary" and if it fails to find the same it throws the above mentioned error.

Comment: Thanks, It works like a charm!!!! but do you know why we should remove these two attributes??

Comment: I never had these two attributes, and still get the same error. Any ideas?

Comment: For me it still fails even if I add android:textColorPrimary in values-v21/styles.xml

Comment: Please consider the answer that [Balman Rawat](http://stackoverflow.com/users/4235532/balman-rawat) gave below. In my case I had to apply both answers.

Comment: @Parag Naik You saved my week thanks :) I love this community.

Comment: In my case i didn't delete this lines, i've just replaced color value on @color/color_alias

Answer (score 41):

I also had same error. In my case some of the resources were in drawable-v21 only. Copy those resources to drawable folder also. This solved the issue for me.

```
Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x0
```

This is the main problem.

Comment: Yup. Same for me. There was a drawable XML file using a `vector` in the `v21` folder and nothing corresponding in the <21 standard folder. Thanks.

Comment: Spot on.. I added the images in drawable-xx but not in drawable. That was the issue

Comment: thanks a lot my selector.xml and other xml file was there too. I jsut copy it and save the problem

Answer (score 30):

If you have already migrated to `androidx`, you should change your layout xml 
from

```
<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView ... />
```

to

```
<com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView ... />
```

Answer (score 15):

I had the same error, I resolved it by adding `app:itemTextColor="@color/a_color"` to my navigation view :

```html
<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/navigation_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="left"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/layout_drawer_header"
    app:menu="@menu/drawer_menu"
    app:itemTextColor="@color/primary"/>
```

You can still use `android:textColorPrimary` and `android:textColorSecondary` in your theme with this method.

Comment: I've tried your workaround from [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30652811/4757307), but still got the same error message. Thanks for your help anyway.

Answer (score 15):

Well
So I was trying to fix this error. And none worked for me. I was not able to figure out solution.
**Scenario:**

I was just going to made a `Navigation Drawer Project` inside Android Studio 2.1.2
And when I try to change the default Android icon in `nav_header_main.xml` I was getting some weird errors. I figured out that I was droping my `PNG` logo into the `...\app\src\main\res\drawable-21`. When I try to put my PNG logo in `...\app\src\main\res\drawable` bam! All weird errors go away.

Following are some of stack trace when I was putting PNG into `drawable-21` folder:

```
08-17 17:29:56.237 6644-6678/myAppName  E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.util.ArrayMap', referenced from method com.android.tools.fd.runtime.Restarter.getActivities
08-17 17:30:01.674 6644-6644/myAppName E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                         java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{myAppName.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #16: Error inflating class <unknown>
                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2372)
                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2424)
                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.handleRelaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3956)
                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:169)
                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1394)
                                                                             at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
                                                                             at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194)
                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5433)
                                                                             at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                                                                             at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
                                                                             at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:924)
                                                                             at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:691)
                                                                             at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
                                                                          Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #16: Error inflating class <unknown>
                                                                             at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:613)
                                                                             at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:687)
                                                                             at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:746)
                                                                             at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489)
                                                                             at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
                                                                             at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352)
                                                                             at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:280)
                                                                             at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140)
                                                                             at edu.uswat.fwd82.findmedoc.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:22)
                                                                             at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5179)
                                                                             at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1146)
                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2336)
                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2424) 
                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.handleRelaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3956) 
                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:169) 
                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1394) 
                                                                             at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107) 
                                                                             at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194) 
                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5433) 
                                                                             at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
                                                                             at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525) 
                                                                             at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:924) 
                                                                             at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:691) 
                                                                             at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 
                                                                          Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
                                                                             at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
                                                                             at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:417)
                                                                             at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:587)
                                                                             at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:687) 
                                                                             at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:746) 
                                                                             at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489) 
                                                                             at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396) 
                                                                             at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352) 
                                                                             at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:280) 
                                                                             at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140) 
                                                                             at edu.uswat.fwd82.findmedoc.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:22) 
                                                                             at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5179) 
                                                                             at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1146) 
                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2336) 
                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2424) 
                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.handleRelaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3956) 
                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:169) 
                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1394) 
                                                                             at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107) 
                                                                             at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194) 
                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5433) 
                                                                             at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
                                                                             at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525) 
                                                                             at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:924) 
                                                                             at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:691) 
                                                                             at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 
                                                                          Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #14: Error inflating class ImageView
                                                                             at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:704)
                                                                             at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:746)
                                                                             at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489)
                                                                             at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
at android.support.design.internal.NavigationMenuPresenter.inflateHeaderView(NavigationMenuPresenter.java:189)
at android.support.design.widget.NavigationView.inflateHeaderView(NavigationView.java:262)
at android.support.design.widget.NavigationView.<init>(NavigationView.java:173)
at android.support.design.widget.NavigationView.<init>(NavigationView.java:95)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method) 
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:417) 
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:587) 
                                                                             at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:687) 
                                                                             at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:746) 
                                                                             at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489) 
                                                                             at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396) 
                                                                             at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352) 
                                                                             at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:280) 
                                                                             at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140) 
                                                                             at edu.uswat.fwd82.findmedoc.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:22) 
                                                                             at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5179) 
                                                                             at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1146) 
                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2336) 
                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2424) 
                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.handleRelaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3956) 
                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:169) 
                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1394) 
                                                                             at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107) 
                                                                             at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194) 
                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5433) 
                                                                             at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
                                                                             at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525) 
                                                                             at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:924) 
                                                                             at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:691) 
                                                                             at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 
                                                                          Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
                                                                             at android.content.res.ResourcesEx.getThemeDrawable(ResourcesEx.java:459)
                                                                             at android.content.res.ResourcesEx.loadDrawable(ResourcesEx.java:435)
                                                                             at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:609)
                                                                             at android.widget.ImageView.<init>(ImageView.java:120)
                                                                             at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView.<init>(AppCompatImageView.java:57)
                                                                             at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView.<init>(AppCompatImageView.java:53)
                                                                             at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater.createView(AppCompatViewInflater.java:106)
                                                                             at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.createView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:980)
                                                                             at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.onCreateView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:1039)
                                                                             at android.support.v4.view.LayoutInflaterCompatHC$FactoryWrapperHC.onCreateView(LayoutInflaterCompatHC.java:44)
                                                                            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:
```

As you can see the above Stack Trace include:

> android.support.design.widget.NavigationView.inflateHeaderView(NavigationView.java:262)
>   at android.support.design.widget.NavigationView.(NavigationView.java:173)
>   at android.support.design.widget.NavigationView.(NavigationView.java:95)

Comment: Very good, thanks for the answer. It seems kind of an answer that was avoided in all other posts.  I was trying to create drawable-v21 and set all in there while I already had drawable folder and just had to place it there

Answer (score 11):

I solved it downgrading in gradle from

```
compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.0'
```

to

```
compile 'com.android.support:design:23.0.1'
```

It seems like I always get problems when I update any component of Android Studio. Getting tired of it.

Comment: Design Support Library is barely related to Android Studio.

Comment: I had the same problem and I could only solve it by Downgrading as @Ton mentioned. Really don't know how Support Library is related to Android Studio Plugin and Platform updates but every time I update some or the other doesn't work for me. I really suggest this answer.

Comment: Rather downgrading I upgraded Compact to match 23.1.0. I think is best to use newer libraries my answer above http://stackoverflow.com/a/38141666/3172518

Answer (score 9):

None of the above fixes worked for me.

What worked for me was changing

```
<item name="android:textColorSecondary">#FFFFFF</item>
```

to

```
<item name="android:textColorSecondary">@color/colorWhite</item>
```

You obviously need to add colorWhite to your colors.xml

Comment: I encountered the inflate exception described in this thread after upgrading the Material Components library from version `1.4.0` to `1.5.0`. The fix for me was as described in this answer: Change the `android:textColorSecondary` value from an unnamed resource to a named resource. I created an issue in the [Material Components for Android](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android) GitHub rep. See [Issue #2595](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/issues/2595).

Answer (score 8):

**Following below steps will surely remove this error.**

- Find the widget causing the error.
- Go the layout file where that widget is declared.
- Check for all the resources (drawables etc.) used in that file.
- Then make sure that resource is there in all versions of drawables (drawable-v21,drawable etc.)

Cheers!!

Answer (score 5):

As Parag Naik correctly mentions (and Lạng Hoàng expands on), the problem arises when setting textColorPrimary to something other than a color state list.  So you could set textColorPrimary as a state list. There is an issue in the android bug tracker about colorPrimary being a state list with only one color: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=172353

So for your theme in styles.xml:

```
<style name="Base.Theme.Hopster" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/primary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/primary_dark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/accent</item>

    <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@color/primary_color_statelist</item>
</style>
```

And the actual primary_color_statelist.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <!-- This is used when the Navigation Item is checked -->
    <item android:color="@color/primary_text_selected" android:state_checked="true" />
    <!-- This is the default text color -->
    <item android:color="@color/primary_text" />
</selector>
```

Answer (score 5):

In my case, I had the same error when I run the app in kitkat API 19 version device. I figured out the problem; I had some drawable resources which was in the drawable-v21 directory (Which is used for versions from API 21 Lollipop). I just put the same resources in the "Drawable" folder to work with the version below API 21. It works. You can put it on the corresponding directory

Answer (score 4):

For me, I encountered this error many times,

*Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.NavigationView* **#28 and #29**

The solution that works for me is that you must match your support design library and your support appcompat library.

`compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'`

`compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.1'`

For me they must match. :) It works for me!

Answer (score 3):

Just for who still get to this issue. I got to the same problem but all the solutions here is not work for me.

Just take alook on NavigationView class with cue from logcat, i found the issue come form this line of code:

```
itemTextColor = this.createDefaultColorStateList(16842806);
```

So, it seem related to itemTextColor as Aenur56 mentioned. So i tried with Aenur56's solution but it doesn't work.

Take a look on the line of code above, i notice that there is ColorStateList. So i create one then set for itemTextColor then it work.

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:color="#00FF00" android:state_checked="true" />
    <item android:color="#000000" />
</selector>
```

Hope it help!

Answer (score 3):

None of the solutions above helped me. I found this on some other webpage and it worked for me - "In project.properties of design library set target to 21 or highest available, then clean design lib, appcomapt and your project and enjoy"

Hope it will help!

Comment: Where is project.properties of design library?

Answer (score 2):

Make sure your drawables for the menu are in the correct folder, mine where put in drawablev21 hence this caused a nullpointer to the resource.

Fixed it buy moving my icons to drawables folder

Answer (score 2):

Generic way of solving issues like `Error inflating class X`:

1. check cause stack trace and there should be `Resources$NotFoundException` like this:

> ```
> Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x7f0b0066
>     at android.content.res.ResourcesImpl.getValue(ResourcesImpl.java:190)
>     at android.content.res.Resources.loadXmlResourceParser(Resources.java:2094)
>     at android.content.res.Resources.getLayout(Resources.java:1111)
>     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:424)
> ```

2. `Resource ID` is actually exact integer from generated R.java file.
3. Find `0x7f0b0066` which will point to the xml file which could not be inflated(found).
4. In most cases that's because directory `layout` doesn't have this resource, but some `layout-XXX` has.
5. And solution is to put resource into all required directories. Or just at least into `layout`.

Answer (score 2):

In my case i had

```
<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView...
```

and in app config:

```
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0'
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
```

So I changed the XML to:

```
com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView...
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem after upgrading the support library and none of the answers worked for me. Finally I solved downloading latest version of build tools and upgrading in build.gradle to `buildToolsVersion "23.0.1"`

Answer (score 1):

One thing to double-check is that you have applied your theme correctly in your AndroidManifest.xml file. In my case, I had omitted the **android:theme** attribute. E.g:

```
<application ... android:theme="@style/Your.Theme.Here" ... >
```

Answer (score 1):

**BETTER I UPGRADED `com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.0`**

as [@Ton said](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33627578/3172518) downgrade `compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.0'`

**BUT Why not to upgrade** `com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1`

**Final upgraded worked for me enjoy**

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.1'
```

So why to use older library. I think is now better to use both design and compact upgraded.

Comment: I upgrade my one, like how @karan wrote, and it works for me.

Answer (score 1):

This error can be caused due to reasons as mentioned below.

1. This problem will likely occur when the version of your appcompat library and design support library doesn't match.
   Example of matching condition

   ```
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.0' // appcompat library

    compile 'com.android.support:design:24.2.0' //design support library
   ```
2. If your theme file in styles have only these two,

   ```
    <item name="colorPrimary">#4A0958</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">#4A0958</item>
   ```

then add ColorAccent too. It should look somewhat like this.

```
 <style name="AppTheme.Base" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">

  <item name="colorPrimary">#4A0958</item>
  <item name="colorPrimaryDark">#4A0958</item>
  <item name="colorAccent">#4A0958</item>

 </style>
```

Comment: i have edited. It means add ColorAccent also if it is not present.

Answer (score 1):

I was also having this same issue, after looking nearly 3 hours I find out that the problem was in my drawable_menu.xml file, it was wrongly written :D

Answer (score 1):

It's weird but clean project and rebuild project worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I found solution...
if you used app:srcCompat change to android:src
this solution worked for me :)

Answer (score 0):

I was facing this error in Xamarin. This was due to some files that were present in **drawable-v21** folder. So I copied those files (probably icon files) to the **drawable** folder and the error was gone.