# Binary inflater :Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.NavigationView

Tags: android, eclipse, navigationview

I followed a tutorial of new component NavigationView in Support Design Library and can't get through this error message

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.encore/com.encore.NavViewActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #27: Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.NavigationView

```
<style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <!--
            Theme customizations available in newer API levels can go in
            res/values-vXX/styles.xml, while customizations related to
            backward-compatibility can go here.
        -->
        <item name="android:colorPrimary">@color/PrimaryColor</item>
        <item name="android:colorPrimaryDark">@color/PrimaryDarkColor</item>
        <item name="windowActionModeOverlay">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowDrawsSystemBarBackgrounds">true</item>
        <item name="android:statusBarColor">@android:color/transparent</item>
    </style>

    <!-- Application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="AppBaseTheme">

        <!-- All customizations that are NOT specific to a particular API-level can go here. -->
    </style>
```

**layout file**

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.encore.NavViewActivity"
android:id="@+id/drawer"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <include
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        layout="@layout/tool_bar"
    />
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/frame"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

    </FrameLayout>

</LinearLayout>

<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/navigation_view"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header"
    app:menu="@menu/drawer"
    />
```

**java file**

```
import android.app.FragmentManager;
import android.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.support.design.widget.NavigationView;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.SubMenu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class NavViewActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    //Defining Variables
    private Toolbar toolbar;
    private NavigationView navigationView;
    private DrawerLayout drawerLayout;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // Initializing Toolbar and setting it as the actionbar
        toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        //Initializing NavigationView
        navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.navigation_view);

        //Setting Navigation View Item Selected Listener to handle the item click of the navigation menu
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(new NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {

            // This method will trigger on item Click of navigation menu
            @Override
            public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem menuItem) {


                //Checking if the item is in checked state or not, if not make it in checked state
                if(menuItem.isChecked()) menuItem.setChecked(false);
                else menuItem.setChecked(true);

                //Closing drawer on item click
                drawerLayout.closeDrawers();

                //Check to see which item was being clicked and perform appropriate action
                switch (menuItem.getItemId()){


                    //Replacing the main content with ContentFragment Which is our Inbox View;
                    case R.id.inbox:
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Inbox Selected",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        ContentFragment fragment = new ContentFragment();
                        android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                        fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.frame,fragment);
                        fragmentTransaction.commit();
                        return true;

                    // For rest of the options we just show a toast on click

                    case R.id.starred:
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Stared Selected",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        return true;
                    case R.id.sent_mail:
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Send Selected",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        return true;
                    case R.id.drafts:
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Drafts Selected",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        return true;
                    case R.id.allmail:
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"All Mail Selected",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        return true;
                    case R.id.trash:
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Trash Selected",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        return true;
                    case R.id.spam:
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Spam Selected",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        return true;
                    default:
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Somethings Wrong",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        return true;
                }
            }
        });

        // Initializing Drawer Layout and ActionBarToggle
        drawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer);
        ActionBarDrawerToggle actionBarDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this,drawerLayout,toolbar,R.string.openDrawer, R.string.closeDrawer){

            @Override
            public void onDrawerClosed(View drawerView) {
                // Code here will be triggered once the drawer closes as we dont want anything to happen so we leave this blank
                super.onDrawerClosed(drawerView);
            }

            @Override
            public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
                // Code here will be triggered once the drawer open as we dont want anything to happen so we leave this blank

                super.onDrawerOpened(drawerView);
            }
        };

        //Setting the actionbarToggle to drawer layout
        drawerLayout.setDrawerListener(actionBarDrawerToggle);

        //calling sync state is necessay or else your hamburger icon wont show up
        actionBarDrawerToggle.syncState();
    }
}
```

Comment: Which is your line 27?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30709419/error-inflating-class-android-support-design-widget-navigationview

Comment: <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView in this line @Jas in layout file

Comment: that post not fixed for me @ IntelliJ Amiya

Answer (score 2):

I also encountered the same problem,Error exactly，Later I found out wrong here：menu->item->`android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_camera"`，this`ic_menu_camera` header has `vector` only used in v21 or higher,so in system 5.0 or less useing can get the problems,than you can copy the following code in values folder and Named "drawables".code:`<resources xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item name="ic_menu_camera" type="drawable">@android:drawable/ic_menu_camera</item>
    <item name="ic_menu_gallery" type="drawable">@android:drawable/ic_menu_gallery</item>
    <item name="ic_menu_slideshow" type="drawable">@android:drawable/ic_menu_slideshow</item>
    <item name="ic_menu_manage" type="drawable">@android:drawable/ic_menu_manage</item>
    <item name="ic_menu_share" type="drawable">@android:drawable/ic_menu_share</item>
    <item name="ic_menu_send" type="drawable">@android:drawable/ic_menu_send</item>
</resources>`

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing `android:layout_gravity="start"`with `android:layout_gravity="right"` inside `NavigationView` layout.

Comment: Set to project target to 21 or highest version available.Clean and run.

Answer (score 0):

check your navigation view by removing one of these and check your code is working or not

- app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header"
- app:menu="@menu/drawer"

if your logcat says cause by resourcenotfoundexception with your above error. issue may be with a icon file/resource file in drawers. if it coming from menu/drawer try changing icons and add icons to drawer folder and to drawer-v21. hope this helps