# Error inflating NavigationView, a Resource is not found

Tags: android, navigationview, android-support-design, android-navigationview

I'm trying the new navigation view and replaced my list view with it but I get an error:

```
10-15 10:49:13.988 17368-17368/com.aufmschoolbliz.app E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-15 10:49:13.988 17368-17368/com.aufmschoolbliz.app E/AndroidRuntime: Process: com.aufmschoolbliz.app, PID: 17368
10-15 10:49:13.988 17368-17368/com.aufmschoolbliz.app E/AndroidRuntime: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.aufmschoolbliz.app/com.aufmschoolbliz.app.activities.Main2Activity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #14: Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
10-15 10:49:13.988 17368-17368/com.aufmschoolbliz.app E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2325)
10-15 10:49:13.988 17368-17368/com.aufmschoolbliz.app E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2387)
10-15 10:49:13.988 17368-17368/com.aufmschoolbliz.app E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151)
10-15 10:49:13.988 17368-17368/com.aufmschoolbliz.app E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303)
10-15 10:49:13.988 17368-17368/com.aufmschoolbliz.app E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
10-15 10:49:13.988 17368-17368/com.aufmschoolbliz.app E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
10-15 10:49:13.988 17368-17368/com.aufmschoolbliz.app E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
10-15 10:49:13.988 17368-17368/com.aufmschoolbliz.app E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
10-15 10:49:13.988 17368-17368/com.aufmschoolbliz.app E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
10-15 10:49:13.988 17368-17368/com.aufmschoolbliz.app E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
10-15 10:49:13.988 17368-17368/com.aufmschoolbliz.app E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
10-15 10:49:13.988 17368-17368/com.aufmschoolbliz.app E/AndroidRuntime:  Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #14: Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
10-15 10:49:13.988 17368-17368/com.aufmschoolbliz.app E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:633)
10-15 10:49:13.988 17368-17368/com.aufmschoolbliz.app E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:743)
10-15 10:49:13.988 17368-17368/com.aufmschoolbliz.app E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:806)
10-15 10:49:13.988 17368-17368/com.aufmschoolbliz.app E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:504)
10-15 10:49:13.988 17368-17368/com.aufmschoolbliz.app E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:414)
10-15 10:49:13.988 17368-17368/com.aufmschoolbliz.app E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:365)
10-15 10:49:13.988 17368-17368/com.aufmschoolbliz.app E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.transition.Scene.enter(Scene.java:175)
10-15 10:49:13.988 17368-17368/com.aufmschoolbliz.app E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.transitionTo(PhoneWindow.java:433)
10-15 10:49:13.988 17368-17368/com.aufmschoolbliz.app E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:376)
10-15 10:49:13.988 17368-17368/com.aufmschoolbliz.app E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:2145)
10-15 10:49:13.988 17368-17368/com.aufmschoolbliz.app E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.aufmschoolbliz.app.activities.Main2Activity.onCreate(Main2Activity.java:13)
10-15 10:49:13.988 17368-17368/com.aufmschoolbliz.app E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5990)
10-15 10:49:13.988 17368-17368/com.aufmschoolbliz.app E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1106)
10-15 10:49:13.988 17368-17368/com.aufmschoolbliz.app E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2278)
10-15 10:49:13.988 17368-17368/com.aufmschoolbliz.app E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2387) 
10-15 10:49:13.988 17368-17368/com.aufmschoolbliz.app E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151) 
10-15 10:49:13.988 17368-17368/com.aufmschoolbliz.app E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303) 
10-15 10:49:13.988 17368-17368/com.aufmschoolbliz.app E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
10-15 10:49:13.988 17368-17368/com.aufmschoolbliz.app E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 
10-15 10:49:13.988 17368-17368/com.aufmschoolbliz.app E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254) 
10-15 10:49:13.988 17368-17368/com.aufmschoolbliz.app E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
10-15 10:49:13.988 17368-17368/com.aufmschoolbliz.app E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
10-15 10:49:13.988 17368-17368/com.aufmschoolbliz.app E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903) 
10-15 10:49:13.988 17368-17368/com.aufmschoolbliz.app E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698) 
10-15 10:49:13.988 17368-17368/com.aufmschoolbliz.app E/AndroidRuntime:  Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
10-15 10:49:13.988 17368-17368/com.aufmschoolbliz.app E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method)
10-15 10:49:13.988 17368-17368/com.aufmschoolbliz.app E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:288)
10-15 10:49:13.988 17368-17368/com.aufmschoolbliz.app E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:607)
10-15 10:49:13.988 17368-17368/com.aufmschoolbliz.app E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:743) 
10-15 10:49:13.988 17368-17368/com.aufmschoolbliz.app E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:806) 
10-15 10:49:13.988 17368-17368/com.aufmschoolbliz.app E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:504) 
10-15 10:49:13.988 17368-17368/com.aufmschoolbliz.app E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:414) 
10-15 10:49:13.988 17368-17368/com.aufmschoolbliz.app E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:365) 
10-15 10:49:13.988 17368-17368/com.aufmschoolbliz.app E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.transition.Scene.enter(Scene.java:175) 
10-15 10:49:13.988 17368-17368/com.aufmschoolbliz.app E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.transitionTo(PhoneWindow.java:433) 
10-15 10:49:13.988 17368-17368/com.aufmschoolbliz.app E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:376) 
10-15 10:49:13.988 17368-17368/com.aufmschoolbliz.app E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:2145) 
10-15 10:49:13.988 17368-17368/com.aufmschoolbliz.app E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.aufmschoolbliz.app.activities.Main2Activity.onCreate(Main2Activity.java:13) 
10-15 10:49:13.988 17368-17368/com.aufmschoolbliz.app E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5990) 
10-15 10:49:13.988 17368-17368/com.aufmschoolbliz.app E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1106) 
10-15 10:49:13.988 17368-17368/com.aufmschoolbliz.app E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2278) 
10-15 10:49:13.988 17368-17368/com.aufmschoolbliz.app E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2387) 
10-15 10:49:13.988 17368-17368/com.aufmschoolbliz.app E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151) 
10-15 10:49:13.988 17368-17368/com.aufmschoolbliz.app E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303) 
10-15 10:49:13.988 17368-17368/com.aufmschoolbliz.app E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
10-15 10:49:13.988 17368-17368/com.aufmschoolbliz.app E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 
10-15 10:49:13.988 17368-17368/com.aufmschoolbliz.app E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254) 
10-15 10:49:13.988 17368-17368/com.aufmschoolbliz.app E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
10-15 10:49:13.988 17368-17368/com.aufmschoolbliz.app E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
10-15 10:49:13.988 17368-17368/com.aufmschoolbliz.app E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903) 
10-15 10:49:13.988 17368-17368/com.aufmschoolbliz.app E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698) 
10-15 10:49:13.988 17368-17368/com.aufmschoolbliz.app E/AndroidRuntime:  Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x0
10-15 10:49:13.988 17368-17368/com.aufmschoolbliz.app E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.content.res.Resources.getValue(Resources.java:1266)
10-15 10:49:13.988 17368-17368/com.aufmschoolbliz.app E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.content.res.Resources.getColorStateList(Resources.java:964)
10-15 10:49:13.988 17368-17368/com.aufmschoolbliz.app E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.design.widget.NavigationView.createDefaultColorStateList(NavigationView.java:338)
10-15 10:49:13.988 17368-17368/com.aufmschoolbliz.app E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.design.widget.NavigationView.<init>(NavigationView.java:124)
10-15 10:49:13.988 17368-17368/com.aufmschoolbliz.app E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.design.widget.NavigationView.<init>(NavigationView.java:88)
10-15 10:49:13.988 17368-17368/com.aufmschoolbliz.app E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method) 
10-15 10:49:13.988 17368-17368/com.aufmschoolbliz.app E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:288) 
10-15 10:49:13.988 17368-17368/com.aufmschoolbliz.app E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:607) 
10-15 10:49:13.988 17368-17368/com.aufmschoolbliz.app E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:743) 
10-15 10:49:13.988 17368-17368/com.aufmschoolbliz.app E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:806) 
10-15 10:49:13.988 17368-17368/com.aufmschoolbliz.app E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:504) 
10-15 10:49:13.988 17368-17368/com.aufmschoolbliz.app E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:414) 
10-15 10:49:13.988 17368-17368/com.aufmschoolbliz.app E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:365) 
10-15 10:49:13.988 17368-17368/com.aufmschoolbliz.app E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.transition.Scene.enter(Scene.java:175) 
10-15 10:49:13.988 17368-17368/com.aufmschoolbliz.app E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.transitionTo(PhoneWindow.java:433) 
10-15 10:49:13.988 17368-17368/com.aufmschoolbliz.app E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:376) 
10-15 10:49:13.988 17368-17368/com.aufmschoolbliz.app E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:2145) 
10-15 10:49:13.988 17368-17368/com.aufmschoolbliz.app E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.aufmschoolbliz.app.activities.Main2Activity.onCreate(Main2Activity.java:13) 
10-15 10:49:13.988 17368-17368/com.aufmschoolbliz.app E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5990) 
10-15 10:49:13.988 17368-17368/com.aufmschoolbliz.app E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1106) 
10-15 10:49:13.988 17368-17368/com.aufmschoolbliz.app E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2278) 
10-15 10:49:13.988 17368-17368/com.aufmschoolbliz.app E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2387) 
10-15 10:49:13.988 17368-17368/com.aufmschoolbliz.app E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151) 
10-15 10:49:13.988 17368-17368/com.aufmschoolbliz.app E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303) 
10-15 10:49:13.988 17368-17368/com.aufmschoolbliz.app E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
10-15 10:49:13.988 17368-17368/com.aufmschoolbliz.app E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 
10-15 10:49:13.988 17368-17368/com.aufmschoolbliz.app E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254) 
10-15 10:49:13.988 17368-17368/com.aufmschoolbliz.app E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
10-15 10:49:13.988 17368-17368/com.aufmschoolbliz.app E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
10-15 10:49:13.988 17368-17368/com.aufmschoolbliz.app E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903) 
10-15 10:49:13.988 17368-17368/com.aufmschoolbliz.app E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
```

I created a new activity, without any custom code, to verify if it's really not working. However, I get the same error.

XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin">


    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:id="@+id/navigationView"/>
        <!--app:headerLayout="@layout/drawer_student_data_header"-->

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Please post your xml code !

Comment: Have you add design support library as dependency ?

Comment: yes, im using 'com.android.support:design:22.2.0'

Comment: Check this link may be it helps you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30709419/error-inflating-class-android-support-design-widget-navigationview

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error about two hours back. I just updated from `Activity` to `AppCompatActivity` and updated the styles to support styles. And the error got resolved.

Update MainActivity class (Or whichever is the activity in which you're inflating the Navigation Menu) from

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
```

to

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
```

And update the styles.xml files (Both normal and `v21`) to

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
```

Hope that helps!