# Binary XML file line #16: Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.NavigationView

Tags: android, android-studio

When i deploy my app to a device with a Android Version below Android 5.0 i got this error. I created the app with die Android Studio Project Assistent and said minSdkVersion=14 so it should be compatible. Can you help me?

Gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "opunktschmidt.weightcontrol"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
        exclude 'META-INF/notice.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/license.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/dependencies.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/LGPL2.1'
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.0.1'
    compile 'joda-time:joda-time:2.8.2'
    compile 'org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:3.4'
}
```

Error:

```
03-12 02:15:15.141 27894-27894/opunktschmidt.weightcontrol E/AndroidRuntime:
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: opunktschmidt.weightcontrol, PID: 27894
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{opunktschmidt.weightcontrol/opunktschmidt.weightcontrol.UI.CalorieDiaryActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #16: Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2334)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2392)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:169)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1280)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:146)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5487)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1283)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1099)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #16: Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:626)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:702)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:761)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:498)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:398)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:354)
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:256)
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:109)
    at opunktschmidt.weightcontrol.UI.CalorieDiaryActivity.onCreate(CalorieDiaryActivity.java:52)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5451)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1093)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2298)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2392) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:169) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1280) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:146) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5487) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1283) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1099) 
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
```

XML File Contains NavigationView:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:openDrawer="start">

    <include
        layout="@layout/app_bar_caloriediary"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:itemTextColor="?android:textColorPrimary"
        app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Comment: put the xml file which contains the NavigationView

Comment: Done in the first post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the reason for the problem: [Android KitKat: android.view.InflateException: Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.NavigationView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35472963/android-kitkat-android-view-inflateexception-error-inflating-class-android-sup)

I dont understand why Android Studio let you create a Android 4.0 compatible project which is not compatible to Android 4.0. -.- You have to investigate to make it Android 4.0 compatible (sorry for bad english).

Answer (score 1):

The problem is, your project is missing the raster resources for pre-lollipop versions.
Check, if you have file `values/drawables.xml`. It seems like you copied some source, but not this file. The file contains references to raster images, that are used as alternatives to the vector images:

```
<resources xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item name="ic_menu_camera" type="drawable">@android:drawable/ic_menu_camera</item>
<item name="ic_menu_gallery" type="drawable">@android:drawable/ic_menu_gallery</item>
<item name="ic_menu_slideshow" type="drawable">@android:drawable/ic_menu_slideshow</item>
<item name="ic_menu_manage" type="drawable">@android:drawable/ic_menu_manage</item>
<item name="ic_menu_share" type="drawable">@android:drawable/ic_menu_share</item>
<item name="ic_menu_send" type="drawable">@android:drawable/ic_menu_send</item>
</resources>
```

Answer (score 0):

Tried all the solutions on stack overflow, nothing worked.

The problem was: I have only a *dimens.xml(v21)* file in the *values* folder. My App will work on the lollipop and above but it will get crashed on android version 4 and less.

```
Since I create a new *dimens.xml* and copy paste all the attributes from 
dimens.xml(v21) to the new dimens.xml.
```

Now the app is working on android version 4 & less.