# Java android crash when add android.support.design.widget.NavigationView

Tags: java, android

When I add this  code in activity_main.xml :

```
<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
        app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer" />
```

My app is crashed . Into build gradle, I added a in dependencies :

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1'
compile 'com.android.support:design:23.0.1'
```

When I remove a android.support.design.widget.NavigationView it is working 
This is a log :

```
Process: com.smok.maps, PID: 16311
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.smok.maps/com.smok.maps.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #431: Binary XML file line #431: Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3253)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3349)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:221)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1794)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:158)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7224)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)
 Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #431: Binary XML file line #431: Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:551)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:429)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:380)
    at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:474)
    at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:2387)
    at com.smok.maps.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:285)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6876)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1135)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3206)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3349)?
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:221)?
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1794)?
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)?
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:158)?
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7224)?
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)?
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230)?
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)?
 Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #431: Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:657)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:776)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:716)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:847)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:810)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:527)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:429)?
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:380)?
    at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:474)?
    at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:2387)?
    at com.smok.maps.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:285)?
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6876)?
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1135)?
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3206)?
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3349)?
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:221)?
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1794)?
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)?
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:158)?
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7224)?
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)?
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230)?
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)?
 Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:631)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:776)?
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:716)?
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:847)?
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:810)?
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:527)?
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:429)?
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:380)?
    at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:474)?
    at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:2387)?
    at com.smok.maps.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:285)?
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6876)?
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1135)?
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3206)?
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3349)?
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:221)?
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1794)?
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)?
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:158)?
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7224)?
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)?
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230)?
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)?
 Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #17: Binary XML file line #17: Error inflating class android.support.design.internal.NavigationMenuView
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:551)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:429)
    at android.support.design.internal.NavigationMenuPresenter.getMenuView(NavigationMenuPresenter.java:98)
    at android.support.design.widget.NavigationView.<init>(NavigationView.java:161)
    at android.support.design.widget.NavigationView.<init>(NavigationView.java:92)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method)?
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:631)?
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:776)?
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:716)?
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:847)?
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:810)?
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:527)?
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:429)?
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:380)?
    at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:474)?
    at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:2387)?
    at com.smok.maps.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:285)?
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6876)?
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1135)?
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3206)?
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3349)?
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:221)?
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1794)?
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)?
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:158)?
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7224)?
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)?
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230)?
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)?
 Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #17: Error inflating class android.support.design.internal.NavigationMenuView
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:657)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:776)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:716)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:498)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:429)?
    at android.support.design.internal.NavigationMenuPresenter.getMenuView(NavigationMenuPresenter.java:98)?
    at android.support.design.widget.NavigationView.<init>(NavigationView.java:161)?
    at android.support.design.widget.NavigationView.<init>(NavigationView.java:92)?
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method)?
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:631)?
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:776)?
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:716)?
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:847)?
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:810)?
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:527)?
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:429)?
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:380)?
    at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:474)?
    at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:2387)?
    at com.smok.maps.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:285)?
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6876)?
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1135)?
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3206)?
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3349)?
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:221)?
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1794)?
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)?
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:158)?
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7224)?
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)?
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230)?
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)?
 Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:631)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:776)?
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:716)?
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:498)?
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:429)?
    at android.support.design.internal.NavigationMenuPresenter.getMenuView(NavigationMenuPresenter.java:98)?
    at android.support.design.widget.NavigationView.<init>(NavigationView.java:161)?
    at android.support.design.widget.NavigationView.<init>(NavigationView.java:92)?
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method)?
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:631)?
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:776)?
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:716)?
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:847)?
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:810)?
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:527)?
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:429)?
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:380)?
    at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:474)?
    at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:2387)?
    at com.smok.maps.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:285)?
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6876)?
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1135)?
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3206)?
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3349)?
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:221)?
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1794)?
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)?
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:158)?
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7224)?
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)?
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230)?
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)?
 Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Failed to resolve attribute at index 0: TypedValue{t=0x2/d=0x7f0100b8 a=-1}
    at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:883)
    at android.widget.AbsListView.<init>(AbsListView.java:1168)
    at android.widget.ListView.<init>(ListView.java:
```

nav_header:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="@dimen/nav_header_height"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark" android:orientation="vertical"
    android:gravity="bottom">

    <ImageView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/nav_header_vertical_spacing"
        android:id="@+id/imageView" />

    <TextView android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/nav_header_vertical_spacing"
        android:text="Andy Point"
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Body1" />

    <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="andypoint@androidtutorialpoint.com"
        android:id="@+id/textView" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30709419/error-inflating-class-android-support-design-widget-navigationview

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya I did this but it doesn't help

Comment: share `nav_header_main`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35673722/binary-xml-file-line-16-error-inflating-class-android-support-design-widget-na Go to this link.

Comment: @SnehaSarkar it doesn't work

Comment: can put full xml file?

Comment: @SanatChandravanshi this is my xml : https://paste.ofcode.org/uM875jaJSBAqcpmqLaEVix

Answer (score 0):

According to your error its pretty much clear that it has failed to inflate navigation menu. Please provide the `@menu/activity_main_drawer` file. And recheck it for external `Strings` or `drawables` and `closed tags`.

Well then you should use

`<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">`

instead of

`<menu xmlns:android="schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">`

and remove `;` after that.

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <group android:checkableBehavior="single">
        <item android:id="@+id/nav_preferences" android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_preferences"
            android:title="Preferences" />
        <item android:id="@+id/nav_about" android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_info_details"
            android:title="About" />
    </group>

</menu>

Comment: This is activity_main_drawer

Comment: see this <menu xmlns:android="schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">; you have terminated it? Try to remove `;`

Comment: It is no working when I changed into this : <menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

 and remove ;

Comment: No you forgot to add `http://` use this `<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/136839/discussion-between-krzysztof-pokrywka-and-pradeep-kumar-kushwaha).

Answer (score 0):

This is a problem of `layout_gravity` at line number 431 Please try to use `layout_gravity = left`

```
<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/nav_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="left"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true" />
```

Comment: Now I got this :   <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="left"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
        app:menu="@menu/main_drawer" />