# Android App not working in 4.0 but working on 5+ Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.NavigationView

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-manifest, android-navigationview

Once run my app in 5.0+ versions it working nicely. but for lower version it gives me errors and not opening up.

This is the error I'm getting:

> Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{lk.myoffers.app.myofferslk/lk.myoffers.app.myofferslk.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #17: Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
>
> 1. Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #17: Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
> 2. Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
> 3. Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x7f020052
> 4. at lk.myoffers.app.myofferslk.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:84)

I have tried every thing on Stack Overflow but the issue is still remaining.

I'm new to android, so what could be the issue?

`setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);` is in line 84.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
    implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener{


public static int pageCount = 1;

private int totalLoadedCount;
private AdListAdapter adapter;

TextView txtUserName;
Button btnReconnect;

private static String LIST_INSTANCE_STATE = "items";
private ArrayList<AdList> adLists = new ArrayList<AdList>();

private ArrayList<MasterCategory> mstCategory = new ArrayList<MasterCategory>();
private MasterCategoryAdapter catAdapter;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    totalLoadedCount = 0;
```

My **activity_main**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<include
    layout="@layout/app_bar_main"
    android:id="@+id/aa"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/nav_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
    app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer"
    />
```

My **Android manifest** file:

```
<activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme1"
        android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

and for the style.xml i have following code lines

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>
<style name="AppTheme1" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    <item name="android:button">@color/colorButton</item>
</style>

<style name="AppTheme.Base" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="colorPrimary">#673AB7</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">#512DA8</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">#00BCD4</item>
</style>

<style name="MIP_theme" parent="AppTheme">
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
</style>

<style name="AppTheme.AppBarOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" />

<style name="AppTheme.PopupOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />
```

I have tried every thing, but it's not working on Android lower than 5
Gradle version set

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'
compile 'com.android.support:design:23.4.0'
```

The **minimum version** is 23.

Here is my build.gradle

```
android {
compileSdkVersion 23
buildToolsVersion "24.0.1"
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "lk.myoffers.app.myofferslk"
    minSdkVersion 14
    targetSdkVersion 23
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
```

}

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.loopj.android:android-async-http:1.4.9'
    compile 'com.github.darsh2:MultipleImageSelect:v0.0.4'
    compile 'com.loopj.android:android-async-http:1.4.9'
    compile 'com.android.volley:volley:1.0.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.4.0'
}
```

Comment: Values-v21 style.xml has <style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowDrawsSystemBarBackgrounds">true</item>
        <item name="android:statusBarColor">@android:color/transparent</item>
    </style>

Comment: Please make sure you don't publish "real" API_KEY etc. values!

Comment: thanks.. this is under testing.. thanks a lot for pointing that out.

Comment: What happens if you don't use a navigation header?

Comment: once I remove app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer" from navigation view its working fine. problem coming from there. by removing header not working but removing drawer menu its working. what might be the issue in **"app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer""**

Comment: Just to be on the safe side: you have a directory **res/menu** and inside that directory, there is a file **activity_main_drawer.xml** ?

Comment: thanks #0X0nosugar issue is with a icon file. I have changed  the menu item icons once by one. this error cause by that.. now its working fine.. Everyone who get this issue check your console. if its says "ResourceNotFoundException" this Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.NavigationView probably rising from one of the menu icon..

Answer (score 1):

Finally after many days and after doing many debugs 
thanks to #0X0nosugar I have checked the navigationview by removing

- app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
- app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer

these two line separately and check the android monitor for errors

```
<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
android:id="@+id/nav_view"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_gravity="start"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer"
/>
```

removing **app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"** doesn't make any changes gives me the same error

But after removing  **app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer"** app works fine and load the left side navigation with no menu item. so as you can see in my error list it says **Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x7f020052**

So I checked by removing custom vector icons in menu item I placed in my activity_main_drawer in res->menu . Its now working fine. problem with a one

```
<item
            android:id="@+id/ic_menu_logout"
            android:icon="@drawable/change_this_icon_with_default_icon_comes_in_android"
            android:title="Logout"
            />
        <item
```

now its working fine.. Everyone who get this issue check your console. if its says "ResourceNotFoundException" this Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.NavigationView probably rising from one of the menu icon..
Finally Works for me! Thanks everyone for your great support

Comment: Wonderful answer. I would like to add, If you have copied your drawable icons from another project before you write the drawer menu, just delete them and copy them again. This answer saved me hours. Man come over for a coffee ! You are a brother !