# NavigationMenu on Android api 14

Tags: android, android-navigation, android-navigationview

Hi i have an app that is working fine on Api 15+ but when i try to open it crashes after the splash screen because  it give NoClassDefFoundError exception on NavigationMenu i have used on my main activity

here is the complete error log

```
W/System.err: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity 

ComponentInfo{com.solodroid.ecommerce/com.solodroid.ecommerce.activities.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #61: Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2377)
W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2429)
W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151)
W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1342)
W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:110)
W/System.err:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5333)
W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:824)
W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:640)
W/System.err:     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
W/System.err: Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #61: Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
W/System.err:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:620)
W/System.err:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:696)
W/System.err:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:755)
W/System.err:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
W/System.err:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
W/System.err:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353)
W/System.err:     at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:280)
W/System.err:     at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140)
W/System.err:     at com.solodroid.ecommerce.activities.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:74)
W/System.err:     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5343)
W/System.err:     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1088)
W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2331)
W/System.err:   ... 11 more
W/System.err: Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
W/System.err:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:594)
W/System.err:   ... 22 more
W/System.err: Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: android.support.design.internal.NavigationMenu
W/System.err:     at android.support.design.widget.NavigationView.<init>(NavigationView.java:104)
W/System.err:     at android.support.design.widget.NavigationView.<init>(NavigationView.java:95)
W/System.err:   ... 25 more
W/dalvikvm: threadid=1: calling UncaughtExceptionHandler
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                  Process: com.solodroid.ecommerce, PID: 10010
                  java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.solodroid.ecommerce/com.solodroid.ecommerce.activities.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #61: Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2377)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2429)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1342)
                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:110)
                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5333)
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:824)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:640)
                      at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
                   Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #61: Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
                      at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:620)
                      at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:696)
                      at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:755)
                      at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
                      at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
                      at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353)
                      at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:280)
                      at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140)
                      at com.solodroid.ecommerce.activities.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:74)
                      at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5343)
                      at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1088)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2331)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2429) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1342) 
                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:110) 
                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5333) 
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:824) 
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:640) 
                      at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 
                   Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
                      at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
                      at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
                      at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:594)
                      at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:696) 
                      at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:755) 
                      at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492) 
                      at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397) 
                      at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353) 
                      at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:280) 
                      at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140) 
                      at com.solodroid.ecommerce.activities.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:74) 
                      at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5343) 
                      at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1088) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2331) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2429) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1342) 
                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:110) 
                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5333) 
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:824) 
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:640) 
                      at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 
                   Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: android.support.design.internal.NavigationMenu
                      at android.support.design.widget.NavigationView.<init>(NavigationView.java:104)
                      at android.support.design.widget.NavigationView.<init>(NavigationView.java:95)
                      at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method) 
                      at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423) 
                      at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:594) 
                      at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:696) 
                      at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:755) 
                      at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492) 
                      at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397) 
                      at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353) 
                      at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:280) 
                      at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140) 
                      at com.solodroid.ecommerce.activities.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:74) 
                      at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5343) 
                      at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1088) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2331) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2429) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1342) 
                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:110) 
                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5333) 
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:824) 
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:640) 
                  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

can somebody help the fix the problem on api 14?

Comment: I guess [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35475589/5674408) answer might solve your problem.

Comment: nope it didnt work