# Android app that runs in emulator running Android 7.0 (API 24) crashes in phone running Android 4.4 (API 19)

Tags: android, xml, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am working on a simple social networking app for Android using Firebase. The main activity of the app is a login screen. Login works fine on the emulator running Android 7.0 (API 24) but crashes on login in Android 4.4 (API 19). Here's the Logcat:

```
06-29 20:32:52.428 31471-31471/com.oliviamontoya.letstradezines E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.oliviamontoya.letstradezines, PID: 31471
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.oliviamontoya.letstradezines/com.oliviamontoya.letstradezines.Main2Activity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #16: Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2181)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2231)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:139)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1401)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5082)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:782)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:598)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
 Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #16: Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:620)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:696)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:755)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353)
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:289)
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:139)
    at com.oliviamontoya.letstradezines.Main2Activity.onCreate(Main2Activity.java:54)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5287)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2145)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2231) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:139) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1401) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5082) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:782) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:598) 
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 
 Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:594)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:696) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:755) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353) 
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:289) 
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:139) 
    at com.oliviamontoya.letstradezines.Main2Activity.onCreate(Main2Activity.java:54) 
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5287) 
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2145) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2231) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:139) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1401) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5082) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:782) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:598) 
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 
 Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x7f020070
    at android.content.res.Resources.getValue(Resources.java:1163)
    at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.loadDrawableFromDelegates(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:331)
    at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.getDrawable(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:196)
    at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.getDrawable(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:189)
    at android.support.v7.content.res.AppCompatResources.getDrawable(AppCompatResources.java:100)
    at android.support.v7.view.menu.MenuItemImpl.getIcon(MenuItemImpl.java:427)
    at android.support.design.internal.NavigationMenuPresenter$NavigationMenuAdapter.prepareMenuItems(NavigationMenuPresenter.java:519)
    at android.support.design.internal.NavigationMenuPresenter$NavigationMenuAdapter.update(NavigationMenuPresenter.java:460)
    at android.support.design.internal.NavigationMenuPresenter.updateMenuView(NavigationMenuPresenter.java:117)
    at android.support.design.widget.NavigationView.inflateMenu(NavigationView.java:252)
    at android.support.design.widget.NavigationView.<init>(NavigationView.java:174)
    at android.support.design.widget.NavigationView.<init>(NavigationView.java:100)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:594) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:696) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:755) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353) 
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:289) 
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:139) 
    at com.oliviamontoya.letstradezines.Main2Activity.onCreate(Main2Activity.java:54) 
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5287) 
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2145) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2231) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:139) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1401) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5082) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:782) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:598) 
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Here is the Java:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    ImageView im;
    TextView tv;
    EditText email;
    EditText password;
    Button b;
    Button b2;
    private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
    private FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener mAuthListener;
    private static final String TAG = "MainActivity";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        mAuthListener = new FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAuthStateChanged(@NonNull FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth) {
                FirebaseUser user = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();
                if (user != null) {
                    // User is signed in
                    Log.d(TAG, "onAuthStateChanged:signed_in:" + user.getUid());
                } else {
                    // User is signed out
                    Log.d(TAG, "onAuthStateChanged:signed_out");
                }
                // ...
            }
        };

        im = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.img);
        tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txt);
        email = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.email);
        password = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.password);
        b = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
        b.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorPrimary));
        b.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);

        b2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
        b2.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorPrimary));
        b2.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
    }

    public void logIn(View view) {
        mAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email.getText().toString(), password.getText().toString())
                .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                        Log.d(TAG, "signInWithEmail:onComplete:" + task.isSuccessful());


                        if (!task.isSuccessful()) {
                            Log.w(TAG, "signInWithEmail:failed", task.getException());
                            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Authorization failed.",
                                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        } else {
                            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Main2Activity.class);
                            startActivity(intent);
                        }

                        // ...
                    }
                });
    }

    public void signUp(View view) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, SignUp.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }

}
```

Here is the XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    tools:context="com.oliviamontoya.letstradezines.MainActivity">
    <ScrollView
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent">
        <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            tools:context="com.oliviamontoya.letstradezines.MainActivity">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/img"
                android:layout_width="200dp"
                android:layout_height="200dp"
                android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"/>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txt"
                android:layout_width="300dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:padding="10dp"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                android:text="Let's Trade Zines is a social network for the zine community!" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/email"
                android:layout_width="300dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:maxLength="30"
                android:hint="Email" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/password"
                android:inputType="textPassword"
                android:layout_width="300dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:ellipsize="start"
                android:maxLength="30"
                android:hint="Password" />

            <GridLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
                xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:columnCount="2"
                android:gravity="center"
                tools:context="com.oliviamontoya.letstradezines.MainActivity">

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/button"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:padding="10dp"
                    android:layout_margin="10dp"
                    android:textSize="20sp"
                    android:onClick="logIn"
                    android:text="Log In" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/button2"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:padding="10dp"
                    android:layout_margin="10dp"
                    android:textSize="20sp"
                    android:onClick="signUp"
                    android:text="Sign Up!" />
            </GridLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Can anyone tell me why it's crashing when I try to log in?

Edit: Here's the Java and XML for Main2Activity:

```
public class Main2Activity extends AppCompatActivity
        implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

    ImageView profileImg;
    TextView usernameDisplay;
    TextView openTrades;
    TextView messages;
    TextView followedFeed;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .setAction("Action", null).show();
            }
        });

        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
        drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
        toggle.syncState();

        NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);

        profileImg = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.profileImg);

        FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
        final FirebaseUser firebaseUser = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
        DatabaseReference databaseReference = database.getReference(firebaseUser.getUid());
        //DatabaseReference child = databaseReference.child(username.getText().toString());
        databaseReference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                User user = dataSnapshot.getValue(User.class);

                if (user.profilePic.isEmpty()) {
                    profileImg.setImageResource(R.mipmap.ic_launcher);
                } else {

                    StorageReference mStorageRef = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference();
                    try {
                        final File localFile = File.createTempFile("profilePic", "jpg");
                        StorageReference ref = mStorageRef.child("images/" + firebaseUser.getUid() + "ProfilePic.jpg");
                        ref.getFile(localFile)
                                .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<FileDownloadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onSuccess(FileDownloadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                                        Bitmap bMap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(localFile.toString());
                                        profileImg.setImageBitmap(bMap);
                                    }
                                }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception exception) {
                                // Handle failed download
                                // ...
                            }
                        });
                    } catch(Exception e) {
                        Toast.makeText(Main2Activity.this, "Error creating file.",
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }

                }

            }
            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });

        usernameDisplay = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.usernameDisplay);
        FirebaseUser user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
        if (user != null) {
            String name = user.getDisplayName();
            usernameDisplay.setText(name);
        }

        openTrades = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.openTrades);
        openTrades.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorPrimary));
        openTrades.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
        messages = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.messages);
        messages.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorPrimary));
        messages.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
        followedFeed = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.followedFeed);
        followedFeed.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorPrimary));
        followedFeed.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
            drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main2, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        if (id == R.id.nav_profile) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, Profile.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        } else if (id == R.id.nav_trades) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_messages) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, Messages.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        } else if (id == R.id.nav_followFeed) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_search) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, Search.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        } else if (id == R.id.nav_logOut) {
            FirebaseAuth.getInstance().signOut();
            finish();
        } else if (id == R.id.nav_share) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_send) {

        }

        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        return true;
    }
}
```

activity_main2.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:openDrawer="start">

    <include
        layout="@layout/app_bar_main2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main2"
        app:menu="@menu/activity_main2_drawer" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

content_main2.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:gravity="center"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context="com.oliviamontoya.letstradezines.Main2Activity"
    tools:showIn="@layout/app_bar_main2">

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:gravity="center"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
            tools:context="com.oliviamontoya.letstradezines.Main2Activity"
            tools:showIn="@layout/app_bar_main2">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/profileImg"
                android:layout_width="150dp"
                android:layout_height="150dp"
                android:gravity="center" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/usernameDisplay"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textSize="25dp"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:layout_margin="10dp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/openTrades"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="200dp"
                android:padding="10dp"
                android:layout_margin="10dp"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="This is where open trades will go." />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/messages"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="200dp"
                android:padding="10dp"
                android:layout_margin="10dp"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="This is where messages will go." />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/followedFeed"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="200dp"
                android:padding="10dp"
                android:layout_margin="10dp"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="This is where followed feed will go." />

        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
```

app_bar_main2.xml and main2.xml are unedited from what was given to me when I added the Navigation Drawer Activity. activity_main2_drawer.xml and nav_header_main2.xml are close to what was given to me with a few edits to text and icons, but I can't fit them all here.

Comment: please try to provide error log

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally figured out the problem. Answer was the accepted answer here: [Android KitKat: android.view.InflateException: Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.NavigationView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35472963/android-kitkat-android-view-inflateexception-error-inflating-class-android-sup)

Answer (score 1):

According to the logcat, it is clear that there is an error in inflating the class "Navigation View".

Navigation View class is added in api level 22.2.0, so it'll not work in api levels lower than that...

I recommend you not using the "navigation view" if you are working with api levels lower than api level 22.

Hope this helps.

Comment: `NavigationView` was added in version 22.2.0 of the Support Library, which supports back to API 9.

Comment: I just read an article that says that the Design Support Library should make NavigationView backwards compatible down to android 2.1. I'm using the Design Support Library, so shouldn't it work?

Comment: The logcat shows the inflating exception in Main2Activity's layout xml file. But, you've posted the layout file that is inflated by MainActivity which doen't even have any navigation view in it. Please post the Main2Activitiy's layout xml file.

Comment: `java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.oliviamontoya.letstradezines/com.oliviamontoya.letstradezines.Main2Activity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #16: Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.NavigationView` ->See this line shows Main2Activity. Post the java and layout files corresponding to this activity

Comment: Okay, I added java and xml for Main2Activity