# Getting exception on android 4.2 but works fine on android 5.0

Tags: android, android-appcompat

I am new to android development. I build my first app which runs perfectly on android 5.0 and above but gives below mentioned exception on devices below 5.0.

I am using following library

```
com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.2.0
com.android.support:design:23.2.0
```

Exception is as follows

```
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.news.example/com.news.firstapp.MainActivity}: 
android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #17: Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2306)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2358)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:156)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1340)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:153)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5299)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:833)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:600)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #17: Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:613)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:687)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:746)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352)
at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:267)
at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:129)
at com.news.firstapp.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:36)
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5182)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1081)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2270)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2358) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:156) 
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1340) 
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:153) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5299) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:833) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:600) 
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:417)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:587)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:687) 
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:746) 
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489) 
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396) 
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352) 
at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:267) 
at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:129) 
at com.news.firstapp.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:36) 
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5182) 
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1081) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2270) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2358) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:156) 
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1340) 
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:153) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5299) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:833) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:600) 
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 
Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x7f02004d
at android.content.res.Resources.getValue(Resources.java:1038)
at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.loadDrawableFromDelegates(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:268)
at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.getDrawable(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:178)
at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.getDrawable(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:173)
at android.support.v7.view.menu.MenuItemImpl.getIcon(MenuItemImpl.java:421)
at android.support.design.internal.NavigationMenuPresenter$NavigationMenuAdapter.prepareMenuItems(NavigationMenuPresenter.java:495)
at android.support.design.internal.NavigationMenuPresenter$NavigationMenuAdapter.update(NavigationMenuPresenter.java:436)
at android.support.design.internal.NavigationMenuPresenter.updateMenuView(NavigationMenuPresenter.java:112)
at android.support.design.widget.NavigationView.inflateMenu(NavigationView.java:241)
at android.support.design.widget.NavigationView.<init>(NavigationView.java:169)
at android.support.design.widget.NavigationView.<init>(NavigationView.java:95)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method) 
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:417) 
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:587) 
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:687) 
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:746) 
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489) 
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396) 
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352) 
at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:267) 
at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:129) 
at com.news.firstapp.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:36) 
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5182) 
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1081) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2270) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2358) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:156) 
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1340) 
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:153) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5299) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:833) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:600) 
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

I am stuck at this point. Your help would be very useful.

Main activity.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:openDrawer="start">

    <include
        layout="@layout/app_bar_main"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
        app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

appbar.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context="com.news.fatafat.MainActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/tabLayout"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            app:tabMode="scrollable"
            app:tabGravity="fill"
            />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>



    <!--<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton-->
        <!--android:id="@+id/fab"-->
        <!--android:layout_width="wrap_content"-->
        <!--android:layout_height="wrap_content"-->
        <!--android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"-->
        <!--android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"-->
        <!--android:src="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_email" />-->

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

build.gradle

```
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.news.firstapp"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.2.0'
}
```

style.xml

```
<resources>

    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    </style>

    <style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    </style>

    <style name="AppTheme.AppBarOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" />

    <style name="AppTheme.PopupOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

</resources>
```

styles.xml(v21)

```
<resources>>

    <style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowDrawsSystemBarBackgrounds">true</item>
        <item name="android:statusBarColor">@android:color/transparent</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

manifest file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>

<application
    android:name=".app.AppController"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".Main2Activity" />
    <activity android:name=".NewschannelFeed" />
    <activity
        android:name=".thirdNews"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_city_news"></activity>
</application>
```

Comment: are you using this android.support.design.widget.NavigationView

Comment: you should share layout of your main activity.

Comment: @HRaval yes i am using

Comment: @Gunhan added code

Comment: are you using two styles values and values-21

Comment: @HRaval added in question

Comment: are you using activity or appcompact activity

Answer (score 0):

It seems like, version of some attributes set in your layout file is greater than your `minSDKVersion`. So check your minimum SDK and/or create different layout files for different SDK.

Edit:

```
<style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar" parent="AppTheme">
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
</style>
```

Similarly for styles.xml (v21)

Comment: I have added build.gradle and layout. can you please check

Comment: Can you also add your `theme` file?

Comment: i don't think i have theme.xml

Comment: cool, update the `parent` of both styles.xml, according to the answer provided.

Answer (score 0):

Please Check that have you use any of the themes that required min API level 21

```
<item name="android:textColorPrimary">#212121</item>
<item name="android:textColorSecondary">#727272</item>
```

The above two are just examples of few, If you have any ! than remove those from your theme and create a separate file for api level 21, and than it may work, It worked for me. Good luck.

Hope i helped

Comment: i have added the styles.xml Is there any thing to not use

Comment: For your reference http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30709419/error-inflating-class-android-support-design-widget-navigationview

Answer (score 0):

well with appcompact activity i am using these two styles

style.xml

```
     <resources>
            <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
                <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
                <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
                <item name="android:windowDrawsSystemBarBackgrounds">true</item>


                <item name="android:colorAccent">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
                <item name="android:colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
                <item name="android:colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>

    </style>

 <style name="AppTheme.AppBarOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" />
    <style name="AppTheme.PopupOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />
    </resources>
```

and v-21-->style.xml

```
    <resources>

        <!-- Base application theme. -->
        <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
             Customize your theme here.
            <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
            <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
            <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
            <item name="colorButtonNormal">@color/colorAccent</item>
            <item name="windowActionModeOverlay">true</item>
</style>
    </resources>
```

Answer (score 0):

Delete your styles.xml(v21) folder and use following in your styles.xml.This style will work for all the android versions.I have added the same style in more than 10 applications so its reliable and tested.

```
    <style name="MyMaterialTheme.Base" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorPrimary</item>

    <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@color/black</item>
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/windowBackground</item>
    <item name="patternViewStyle">@style/PatternView.Holo</item>
    </style>
```

and use the above style in your activity like this

```
 <activity
        android:name=".activity.ContactUsActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@style/MyMaterialTheme.Base" />
```

Let me know if you still face any issue.Mark this up if it helps