# NavigationView theme error

Tags: java, android

I made an app with NavigationView without ActionBar and when I change my theme from

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.Design.NoActionBar">
```

to

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="android:Theme.DeviceDefault.NoActionBar">
```

this error appears:

> Error inflating class android.support.design.internal.NavigationMenuItemView

Why?

Comment: Hi! Did you tried this answer already?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30709419/error-inflating-class-android-support-design-widget-navigationview

Comment: yes, but with no luck