# Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.NavigationView

Tags: java, android, xml, android-studio

I followed a tutorial of  NavigationView and can't get through this error message :

```
 Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
```

Tutorial link: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mtOztjHmM0c

I tried every solution given to this question on stackoverflow from here:
[Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.NavigationView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30709419/error-inflating-class-android-support-design-widget-navigationview)

but the error message still exists

**activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"

tools:context="com.mandeepsinghshekhawat95gmail.moneymemo.MainActivity">
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"

    >
    <include
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        layout="@layout/toolbar_layout"
        />
</LinearLayout>

<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/navigation_view"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    app:menu="@menu/drawer_menu"
    />
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

**build.gradle**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 23
buildToolsVersion "23.0.3"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.mandeepsinghshekhawat95gmail.moneymemo"
    minSdkVersion 21
    targetSdkVersion 23
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}

dependencies {
   compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
   testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
   compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.3.0'
   compile 'com.android.support:design:23.3.0'
}
```

**Project build.gradle**

```
buildscript {
repositories {
    jcenter()
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.0.0'

    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
}
}

allprojects {
   repositories {
       jcenter()
    }
  }

 task clean(type: Delete) {
  delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

**styles.xml**

```
<resources>

<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>
```

**drawer_menu.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<group android:checkableBehavior="single">

    <item
    android:id="@+id/home_id"
    android:title="Home"
    android:icon="@drawable/home"
    ></item>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/id_message"
        android:title="Message"
        android:icon="@drawable/message"
        ></item>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/id_settings"
        android:title="Home"
        android:icon="@drawable/settings"
        ></item>
</group>

<item android:title="Social"
    >

    <menu>
        <item android:title="Add to Group"
            android:id="@+id/add_to_group"
            android:icon="@drawable/person"
            ></item>
        <item android:title="Group"
            android:id="@+id/id_group"
            android:icon="@drawable/group"
            ></item>
        <item android:title="Share"
            android:id="@+id/share"
            android:icon="@drawable/share"
            ></item>
    </menu>
</item>
 </menu>
```

**toolbar_layout.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:id="@+id/toolbar"
android:background="?attr/colorPrimaryDark"
android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
>

</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
package com.mandeepsinghshekhawat95gmail.moneymemo;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

Toolbar toolbar;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    toolbar=(Toolbar)findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
 }
}
```

**StackTrace**

```
 java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.mandeepsinghshekhawat95gmail.moneymemo/com.mandeepsinghshekhawat95gmail.moneymemo.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #23: Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
                                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2339)
                                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2413)
                                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:155)
                                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1317)
                                                                                            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                                            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
                                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5343)
                                                                                            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                                                                                            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:907)
                                                                                            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:702)
                                                                                         Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #23: Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
                                                                                            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:633)
                                                                                            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:743)
                                                                                            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:806)
                                                                                            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:504)
                                                                                            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:414)
                                                                                            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:365)
                                                                                            at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:276)
                                                                                            at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:136)
                                                                                            at com.mandeepsinghshekhawat95gmail.moneymemo.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:13)
                                                                                            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6010)
                                                                                            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1129)
                                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2292)
                                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2413) 
                                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:155) 
                                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1317) 
                                                                                            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                                            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 
                                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5343) 
                                                                                            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                                            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
                                                                                            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:907) 
                                                                                            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:702) 
                                                                                         Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
                                                                                            at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method)
                                                                                            at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:288)
                                                                                            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:607)
                                                                                            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:743) 
                                                                                            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:806) 
                                                                                            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:504) 
                                                                                            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:414) 
                                                                                            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:365) 
                                                                                            at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:276) 
                                                                                            at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:136) 
                                                                                            at com.mandeepsinghshekhawat95gmail.moneymemo.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:13) 
                                                                                            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6010) 
                                                                                            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1129) 
                                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2292) 
                                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2413) 
                                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:155) 
                                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1317) 
                                                                                            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                                            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 
                                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5343) 
                                                                                            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                                            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
                                                                                            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:907) 
                                                                                            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:702) 
                                                                                         Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a 216000012 byte allocation with 16777216 free bytes and 95MB until OOM
                                                                                            at dalvik.system.VMRuntime.newNonMovableArray(Native Method)
                                                                                            at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeAsset(Native Method)
                                                                                            at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:609)
                                                                                            at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream(BitmapFactory.java:444)
                                                                                            at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromResourceStream(Drawable.java:988)
                                                                                            at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawableForCookie(Resources.java:2477)
                                                                                            at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:2384)
                                                                                            at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable(Resources.java:787)
                                                                                            at android.content.Context.getDrawable(Context.java:403)
                                                                                            at android.support.v4.content.ContextCompatApi21.getDrawable(ContextCompatApi21.java:26)
                                                                                            at android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat.getDrawable(ContextCompat.java:321)
                                                                                            at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.getDrawable(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:201)
                                                                                            at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.getDrawable(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:191)
                                                                                            at android.support.v7.view.menu.MenuItemImpl.getIcon(MenuItemImpl.java:421)
                                                                                            at android.support.design.internal.NavigationMenuPresenter$NavigationMenuAdapter.appendTransparentIconIfMissing(NavigationMenuPresenter.java:519)
                                                                                            at android.support.design.internal.NavigationMenuPresenter$NavigationMenuAdapter.prepareMenuItems(NavigationMenuPresenter.java:488)
                                                                                            at android.support.design.internal.NavigationMenuPresenter$NavigationMenuAdapter.update(NavigationMenuPresenter.java:436)
                                                                                            at android.support.design.internal
```

Answer (score 1):

try to use this library it worked for me
compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.1'

Comment: Use the comment section for the answers like this.,