# Error inflating NavigationView class -- android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio, android-navigationview

I'm trying to use NavigationView, but when I try to launch the app to the phone an error happens.

```
Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #16: Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
```

The xml files are:

*activity_main:*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <!--Contenido Principal-->
    <include layout="@layout/main_content" />

    <!--Menú Deslizante-->
    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header"
        app:menu="@menu/nav_menu"/>

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

*Gradle File:*

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.shudy.XXXXXX"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'

    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.4.0'

    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:9.0.2'

    compile 'com.github.orhanobut:logger:1.12'
    compile 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:1.3.0'

}
```

*Error*

```
06-16 14:00:16.883 10658-10658/com.shudy.XXXXX E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                        Process: com.shudy.XXXXX, PID: 10658
                                                                        java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.shudy.XXXXX/com.shudy.XXXXX.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #16: Binary XML file line #16: Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3253)
                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3349)
                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:221)
                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1794)
                                                                            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:158)
                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7224)
                                                                            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230)
                                                                            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)
```

I really don't know what is going, because is supposed taht is all OK.

**EDIT, addded styles files**

*style*

```
<resources>

    <style name="Theme.EyeSky" parent="Base.AppTheme"/>

    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="Base.AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/window_background</item>
    </style>

</resources>
```

*style-v21*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <style name="Theme.EyeSky" parent="Base.AppTheme">
        <item name="android:windowDrawsSystemBarBackgrounds">true</item>
        <item name="android:statusBarColor">@android:color/transparent</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

**EDIT 2**

I'm using Android SDK Platform-Tools 23.1.0, and in gradle file:

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.3"
```

*menu*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <group android:checkableBehavior="single">
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_home"
            android:checked="true"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_home"
            android:title="@string/home_item"/>
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_map"
            android:checked="true"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_home"
            android:title="@string/map_item"/>

        <!-- Configuration section-->

        <item
            android:id="@+id/configuration_section"
            android:title="@string/configuration_item">
            <menu>
                <item
                    android:id="@+id/nav_log_out"
                    android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_lock_power_off"
                    android:title="@string/log_out_item"/>
            </menu>
        </item>
    </group>

</menu>
```

---

**EDIT: Solution Found.**

The problem was at navigation_header file. I had a ImageView, that for some reason, the height and width, didn't take it for the dimens.xml file. SO, I set it manually, and worked perfect.
Here is how finally look,, this ImaveView (from a library)

```
<de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
        android:id="@+id/profile_image"
        android:layout_width="64dp"
        android:layout_height="64dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:src="@drawable/perfil2"
        app:border_color="@android:color/white"
        app:border_width="1dp"/>
```

Comment: place your style.xml

Comment: Done @AbhishekPatel

Comment: Manifest has in application tag -->` android:theme="@style/Theme.EyeSky"`

Comment: Can you add the menu.xml?

Comment: done @josemigallas thanks!

Comment: @Shudy try this and let me know it's working or not.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30709419/error-inflating-class-android-support-design-widget-navigationview

Comment: @AbhishekPatel nope, I tried without "Color[Primary/SEcondary]Text" in colors.xml, and in style file, there is no reference of any "android:textColor.."

Comment: there are many upvoted answer try that also because it was a common problem for all developers

Comment: In android 6 (more or less the same code) is running without issues, so it could be related with the header? Have your tried cleaning/rebuilding the project?

Comment: I found the problem. In the dimens.xml I had set some dimensions for imageview in navigation_header.xml In code, AS, don't marked any problem , but for some reason, didn't take the the dimensions. after put it "manually" `android:layout_width/height=64dp` it worked. Thanks for the help!