# Error Inflating Navigation View

Tags: android

I am getting this error running the app on devices below Android 5.

I have seen similar questions but all of them resolved it by updating their dependencies but all mine are up to date what els could be causing this?

Logcat

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                     java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.candyx.testapp.activity.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #16: Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2059)
                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2084)
                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:130)
                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1195)
                                                                         at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
                                                                         at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
                                                                         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                                                                         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
                                                                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
                                                                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
                                                                         at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
                                                                      Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #16: Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
                                                                         at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:613)
                                                                         at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:687)
                                                                         at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:746)
                                                                         at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489)
                                                                         at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
                                                                         at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352)
                                                                         at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:284)
                                                                         at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140)
                                                                         at com.candyx.testapp.activity.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:34)
                                                                         at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5008)
                                                                         at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1079)
                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2023)
                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2084) 
                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:130) 
                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1195) 
                                                                         at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
                                                                         at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137) 
                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745) 
                                                                         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
                                                                         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511) 
                                                                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786) 
                                                                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553) 
                                                                         at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 
                                                                      Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
                                                                         at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
                                                                         at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:417)
                                                                         at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:587)
                                                                         at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:687) 
                                                                         at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:746) 
                                                                         at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489) 
                                                                         at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396) 
                                                                         at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352) 
                                                                         at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:284) 
                                                                         at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140) 
                                                                         at com.candyx.testapp.activity.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:34) 
                                                                         at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5008) 
                                                                         at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1079) 
                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2023) 
                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2084) 
                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:130) 
                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1195) 
                                                                         at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
                                                                         at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137) 
                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745) 
                                                                         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
                                                                         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511) 
                                                                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786) 
                                                                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553) 
                                                                         at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 
                                                                      Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x7f02006f
                                                                         at android.content.res.Resources.getValue(Resources.java:1013)
                                                                         at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.loadDrawableFromDelegates(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:324)
                                                                         at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.getDrawable(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:189)
                                                                         at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.getDrawable(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:182)
                                                                         at android.support.v7.content.res.AppCompatResources.getDrawable(AppCompatResources.java:100)
                                                                         at android.support.v7.view.menu.MenuItemImpl.getIcon(MenuItemImpl.java:421)
                                                                         at android.support.design.internal.NavigationMenuPresenter$NavigationMenuAdapter.prepareMenuItems(NavigationMenuPresenter.java:505)
                                                                         at android.support.design.internal.NavigationMenuPresenter$NavigationMenuAdapter.update(NavigationMenuPresenter.java:446)
                                                                         at android.support.design.internal.NavigationMenuPresenter.updateMenuView(NavigationMenuPresenter.java:112)
                                                                         at android.support.design.widget.NavigationView.inflateMenu(NavigationView.java:248)
                                                                         at android.support.design.widget.NavigationView.<init>(NavigationView.java:171)
                                                                         at android.support.design.widget.NavigationView.<init>(NavigationView.java:97)
                                                                         at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method) 
                                                                         at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:417) 
                                                                         at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:587) 
                                                                         at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:687) 
                                                                         at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:746) 
                                                                         at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489) 
                                                                         at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396) 
                                                                         at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352) 
                                                                         at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:284) 
                                                                         at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140) 
                                                                         at com.candyx.testapp.activity.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:34) 
                                                                         at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5008) 
                                                                         at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1079) 
                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2023) 
                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2084) 
                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:130) 
                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1195) 
                                                                         at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
                                                                         at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137) 
                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745) 
                                                                         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
                                                                         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511) 
                                                                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786) 
                                                                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553) 
                                                                         at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Dependencies

```
dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.0'
compile 'com.android.support:design:24.2.0'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:24.2.0'
compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:24.2.0'
```

activity_main.xml

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
tools:openDrawer="start">

<include
    layout="@layout/app_bar_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/nav_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:background="#e0e0e0"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
    app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

nav_header_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="@dimen/nav_header_height"
android:background="@drawable/bg_image"
android:gravity="bottom"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark">

</LinearLayout>
```

styles.xml

```
<resources>

<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>

<style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
</style>

<style name="AppTheme.AppBarOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" />

<style name="AppTheme.PopupOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />
```

Comment: show me your .java file

Comment: post you code....

Comment: what do you want to see there is so much

Comment: show te XML file, and point line #16 in it. the error is there

Comment: show your nav_header_main.xml and activity_main_drawer.xml

Comment: did you try this answer on stackoverflow.. http://stackoverflow.com/a/30739270/3678308 ?

Comment: @Java coder Yes I did

Comment: Open R.java file and search for 0x7f02006f. That's the id of resource which is missing. Probably because of wrong configuration of resources (eg. image is put under drawable-v21 instead of drawable folder)

Comment: From `android.support.v7.view.menu.MenuItemImpl.getIcon(MenuItemImpl.java:421)` I see that the problem is with the icon of menu item

Comment: @Victor K Yes thanks that solved

Comment: add the following - app:itemTextColor to your NavigationView