# Android "Unable to start activity" error on KitKat only?

Tags: android, android-studio, runtime-error, android-navigationview

I am getting an error that, for some reason, ONLY appears when I run my Android App through KitKat, every other software above KitKat works just fine. Here is the error:

```
0:40.895 3004-3004/<COM DOT IS HERE> E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
  Process: com.company.apptest, PID: 3004
  java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.company.apptest/com.company.apptest.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #16: Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
      at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2195)
      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
      at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
      at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
   Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #16: Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
      at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:621)
      at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:697)
      at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:756)
      at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
      at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
      at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353)
      at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:280)
      at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140)
      at com.company.apptest.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:28)
      at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
      at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
      at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2159)
      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245) 
      at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135) 
      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196) 
      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136) 
      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017) 
      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779) 
      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595) 
      at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 
   Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
      at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
      at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
      at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:595)
      at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:697) 
      at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:756) 
      at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492) 
      at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397) 
      at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353) 
      at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:280) 
      at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140) 
      at com.company.apptest.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:28) 
      at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231) 
      at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087) 
      at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2159) 
      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245) 
      at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135) 
      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196) 
      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136) 
      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017) 
      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779) 
      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595) 
      at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 
   Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x7f02004b
      at android.content.res.Resources.getValue(Resources.java:1123)
      at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.loadDrawableFromDelegates(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:321)
      at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.getDrawable(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:197)
      at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.getDrawable(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:192)
      at android.support.v7.view.menu.MenuItemImpl.getIcon(MenuItemImpl.java:421)
      at android.support.design.internal.NavigationMenuPresenter$NavigationMenuAdapter.prepareMenuItems(NavigationMenuPresenter.java:495)
      at android.support.design.internal.NavigationMenuPresenter$NavigationMenuAdapter.update(NavigationMenuPresenter.java:436)
      at android.support.design.internal.NavigationMenuPresenter.updateMenuView(NavigationMenuPresenter.java:112)
      at android.support.design.widget.NavigationView.inflateMenu(NavigationView.java:245)
      at android.support.design.widget.NavigationView.<init>(NavigationView.java:169)
      at android.support.design.widget.NavigationView.<init>(NavigationView.java:95)
      at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method) 
      at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423) 
      at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:595) 
      at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:697) 
      at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:756) 
      at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492) 
      at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397) 
      at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353) 
      at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:280) 
      at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140) 
      at com.company.apptest.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:28) 
      at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231) 
      at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087) 
      at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2159) 
      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245) 
      at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135) 
      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196) 
      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136) 
      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017) 
      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779) 
      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595) 
      at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

This is the activity_main file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout      xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
tools:openDrawer="start">

<include
    layout="@layout/app_bar_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/nav_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
    app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

This is line 28 of the MainActivity.java file:

```
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
```

My activity_main.xml is the in res/layout folder

Comment: can you add the exact line where you get the error as described by Caused by line

Comment: What is line 28 of your MainActivity.java?

Comment: **1.** please post your MainActivity's xml. **2.** also state the folder name in which that xml is placed.

Comment: This is not the full activity_main.xml, is it?

Comment: Sorry, just corrected that. Full xml is there now.

Comment: I guess you have a similar issue like this question - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30709419/error-inflating-class-android-support-design-widget-navigationview. It could be your theme.

Comment: Check that before, but I couldn't find textColorPrimary or textColorSecondary anywhere in my theme

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have a navigationview in main activity...go to layout file of your main activity in line 16 you have a resource maybe that is a vector or you have it in one drawable folder...
you can define vector drawable in Android 5(api 21) and above

for testing this answer try to remove that resource from your layout and run

check your nav_header_main layout  resources and your menu/activity_main_drawer resources

in some of that files you have resources that could be vector or ...

for example in your menu file you have items like this:

```
<item
            android:id="@+id/nav_contact_uni"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_gallery"
            android:title="your-title" />
```

check ic_menu_gallery file in drawable

if your icon drawable files is vector you can add this lines in your main activity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    static {
        AppCompatDelegate.setCompatVectorFromResourcesEnabled(true);
    }

    ...
}
```

or you can add this in build.gradle:

```
compile 'com.android.support:support-vector-drawable:24.2.0'
```

Comment: Line 16 of my resource file is <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView so what should I do?

Comment: for testing what problem you have you can remove  ...if your icon file is vector you can add a method to solve your problem...

Comment: Thank you so much!!  I believe that the resources/images I was using were too big, so when I removed them the program seemed to run smoothly.

Answer (score 0):

Please check the version of your appcompat library and design support library is same in gradle file.
Just Example:

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1' 
compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.1'
```

use latest version.Hope it helps. [details](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30709419/error-inflating-class-android-support-design-widget-navigationview)

Thank You

Comment: Yep, they're both 23.4.0