# Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.NavigationView in my app

Tags: java, android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I've got a problem with my app.
This is error i'm getting:

```
 java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.justfashion/com.justfashion.ActivityMainWallet}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #91: Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2521)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2595)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:178)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1470)
                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:111)
                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5631)
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:959)
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:754)
               Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #91: Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:633)
                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:743)
                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:806)
                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:504)
                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:414)
                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:365)
                  at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:280)
                  at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140)
                  at com.material.BaseActivity.setContentView(BaseActivity.java:46)
                  at com.justfashion.ActivityMainWallet.onCreate(ActivityMainWallet.java:121)
                  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6092)
                  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1112)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2468)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2595) 
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:178) 
                  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1470) 
                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:111) 
                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194) 
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5631) 
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:959) 
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:754) 
               Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
                  at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method)
                  at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:288)
                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:607)
                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:743) 
                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:806) 
                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:504) 
                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:414) 
                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:365) 
                  at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:280) 
                  at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140) 
                  at com.material.BaseActivity.setContentView(BaseActivity.java:46) 
                  at com.justfashion.ActivityMainWallet.onCreate(ActivityMainWallet.java:121) 
                  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6092) 
                  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1112) 
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2468) 
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2595) 
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:178) 
                  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1470) 
                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:111) 
                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194) 
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5631) 
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:959) 
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:754) 
               Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: android.support.design.internal.NavigationMenuPresenter
                  at android.support.design.widget.NavigationView.<init>(NavigationView.java:80)
                  at android.support.design.widget.NavigationView.<init>(NavigationView.java:92)
                  at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method) 
                  at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:288) 
                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:607) 
                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:743) 
                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:806) 
                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:504) 
                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:414) 
                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:365) 
                  at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:280) 
                  at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140) 
                  at com.material.BaseActivity.setContentView(BaseActivity.java:46) 
                  at com.justfashion.ActivityMainWallet.onCreate(ActivityMainWallet.java:121) 
                  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6092) 
                  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1112) 
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2468) 
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2595) 
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:178) 
                  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1470) 
                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:111) 
                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194) 
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5631) 
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
```

Here is a #91+ lines of my XML:

```
  <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/navigation_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:background="@color/md_white_1000"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_drawer_header"
    app:menu="@menu/menu_drawer"
    app:itemTextAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Menu"
    android:clipToPadding="false">
```

Here is a a baseactivity error lines:

```
    @Override
public void setContentView(int layoutResID) {
    super.setContentView(layoutResID);
    initAppCompatDesign();
    initViews();
```

And the same with activitymainwallet:

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main_activity);
        AppLovinSdk.initializeSdk(this);
        HeyzapAds.start(getString(R.string.heyzap_app_id), this);
        //HeyzapAds.startTestActivity(this);
```

The problem appears when I changed something in my gradle (app) file:

```
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.1"
    useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'





    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.justfashion"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 23
        multiDexEnabled true
    }

    signingConfigs {
        release {
            storeFile file("najnowszy.jks")
            storePassword "asiunia"
            keyAlias "production"
            keyPassword "asiunia"
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            //minifyEnabled false
            //proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
            //signingConfig signingConfigs.release
            //multiDexEnabled true
        }
    }
}

dependencies {

    //compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.3.0'
    compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.+'
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.3.1'
    compile files('libs/NativeXMonetizationSDK_v5.4.12.jar')
    compile files('libs/Parse-1.3.8.jar')
    compile files('libs/SuperRewards-3.1b.jar')
    compile files('libs/TrialpayAndroidSdk.jar')
    compile files('libs/acra-4.5.0.jar')
    compile files('libs/adcolony.jar')
    compile files('libs/adscendmedia1.0.1.jar')
    compile files('libs/dagger-1.2.2.jar')
    compile files('libs/javax.inject-1.jar')
    compile files('libs/mediationsdk-6.2.2.jar')
    compile files('libs/nineoldandroids-2.4.0.jar')
    compile files('libs/personasdk1.1.jar')
    compile files('libs/picasso-2.4.0.jar')
    compile files('libs/tapjoyconnectlibrary.jar')
    compile files('libs/vungle-publisher-adaptive-id-3.3.1.jar')
    compile files('libs/chartboost.jar')
    compile files('libs/applovin-sdk-6.1.5.jar')
    compile files('libs/heyzap.jar')
    compile files('libs/revmob.jar')
    compile project(':appGradeLib')
    //compile project(':sensiblefacebooksdk')
    compile project(':googleplayserviceslib')
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.0.0'
    compile files('libs/AdxmiCustomizedSdk_v1.2.0_2015-11-13.jar')
    compile files('libs/AdxmiSdk_v5.4.0_2015-11-12.jar')
    compile project(':unity-ads')
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.0'
    compile files('libs/org.apache.http.legacy.jar')
}
```

I don't remember which one I was changed. Is a problem with gradle? Thanks You a lot!

Comment: Post your styles.xml?

Comment: @Raghavendra http://pastebin.com/h1fw32Cj

Comment: Hope this will hep you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30709419/error-inflating-class-android-support-design-widget-navigationview

Comment: @Raghavendra tried it, not working

Answer (score -1):

Try:

`compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.0.0'`

The v4 support library is needed to instantiate a `NavigationView` which is part of the Navigation Drawer UI.

Comment: The latest is `25.0.0`.

Comment: this is included as part of the `appcompat-v7:23.0.0` library