# How can I login as a Navigation drawer activity after clicking the login button?

Tags: java, android, navigation-drawer

I have a small issues. Here I am having three activities, LoginActivity, RegisterActivity and UserActivity(NavigationDrawer activity),I should be navigated to the UserActivity(which is the NavigaitonDrawer Activity)as soon as I press the login button,But  When i enter the credentials and  clicking the login button, the app force closes automatically.Please Help me.Here I have posted my entire java code:

LoginActivity.java

```
package com.androidtutorialpoint.androidlogin;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Toast;
import com.android.volley.Request;
import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.VolleyError;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;


public class LoginActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static final String TAG = "LoginActivity";
    private static final String URL_FOR_LOGIN = "http://192.168.43.97/android_login_example/login.php";
    ProgressDialog progressDialog;
    private EditText loginInputEmail, loginInputPassword;
    private Button btnlogin;
    private Button btnLinkSignup;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);
        loginInputEmail = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.login_input_email);
        loginInputPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.login_input_password);
        btnlogin = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_login);
        btnLinkSignup = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_link_signup);
        // Progress dialog
        progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
        progressDialog.setCancelable(false);

        btnlogin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                loginUser(loginInputEmail.getText().toString(),
                        loginInputPassword.getText().toString());
            }
        });

        btnLinkSignup.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), RegisterActivity.class);
                startActivity(i);
            }
        });
    }

    private void loginUser( final String email, final String password) {
        // Tag used to cancel the request
        String cancel_req_tag = "login";
        progressDialog.setMessage("Logging you in...");
        showDialog();
        StringRequest strReq = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST,
                URL_FOR_LOGIN, new Response.Listener<String>() {

            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {
                Log.d(TAG, "Register Response: " + response.toString());
                hideDialog();
                try {
                    JSONObject jObj = new JSONObject(response);
                    boolean error = jObj.getBoolean("error");

                    if (!error) {
                        String user = jObj.getJSONObject("user").getString("name");
                        // Launch User activity
                        Intent intent = new Intent(
                                LoginActivity.this,
                                UserActivity.class);
                        intent.putExtra("username", user);
                        startActivity(intent);
                        finish();
                    } else {

                        String errorMsg = jObj.getString("error_msg");
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                errorMsg, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Login Error: " + error.getMessage());
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                hideDialog();
            }
        }) {

            @Override
            protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
                // Posting params to login url
                Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
                params.put("email", email);
                params.put("password", password);
                return params;
            }

        };
        // Adding request to request queue
        AppSingleton.getInstance(getApplicationContext()).addToRequestQueue(strReq,cancel_req_tag);
    }

    private void showDialog() {
        if (!progressDialog.isShowing())
            progressDialog.show();
    }
    private void hideDialog() {
        if (progressDialog.isShowing())
            progressDialog.dismiss();
    }

}
```

RegisterActivity.java

```
package com.androidtutorialpoint.androidlogin;

import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.RadioGroup;
import android.widget.Toast;
import com.android.volley.Request;
import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.VolleyError;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;


public class RegisterActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static final String TAG = "RegisterActivity";
    private static final String URL_FOR_REGISTRATION = "http://192.168.43.97/android_login_example/register.php";
    ProgressDialog progressDialog;

    private EditText signupInputName, signupInputEmail, signupInputPassword, signupInputAge;
    private Button btnSignUp;
    private Button btnLinkLogin;
    private RadioGroup genderRadioGroup;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_register);

        // Progress dialog
        progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
        progressDialog.setCancelable(false);

        signupInputName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.signup_input_name);
        signupInputEmail = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.signup_input_email);
        signupInputPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.signup_input_password);
        signupInputAge = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.signup_input_age);

        btnSignUp = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_signup);
        btnLinkLogin = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_link_login);

        genderRadioGroup = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.gender_radio_group);
        btnSignUp.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                submitForm();
            }
        });
        btnLinkLogin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),LoginActivity.class);
                startActivity(i);
            }
        });
    }

    private void submitForm() {

        int selectedId = genderRadioGroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
        String gender;
        if(selectedId == R.id.female_radio_btn)
            gender = "Female";
        else
            gender = "Male";

        registerUser(signupInputName.getText().toString(),
                     signupInputEmail.getText().toString(),
                     signupInputPassword.getText().toString(),
                     gender,
                     signupInputAge.getText().toString());
    }

    private void registerUser(final String name,  final String email, final String password,
                              final String gender, final String dob) {
        // Tag used to cancel the request
        String cancel_req_tag = "register";

        progressDialog.setMessage("Adding you ...");
        showDialog();

        StringRequest strReq = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST,
                URL_FOR_REGISTRATION, new Response.Listener<String>() {

            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {
                Log.d(TAG, "Register Response: " + response.toString());
                hideDialog();

                try {
                    JSONObject jObj = new JSONObject(response);
                    boolean error = jObj.getBoolean("error");

                    if (!error) {
                        String user = jObj.getJSONObject("user").getString("name");
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Hi " + user +", You are successfully Added!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                        // Launch login activity
                        Intent intent = new Intent(
                                RegisterActivity.this,
                                LoginActivity.class);
                        startActivity(intent);
                        finish();
                    } else {

                        String errorMsg = jObj.getString("error_msg");
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                errorMsg, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Registration Error: " + error.getMessage());
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                hideDialog();
            }
        }) {
            @Override
            protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
                // Posting params to register url
                Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
                params.put("name", name);
                params.put("email", email);
                params.put("password", password);
                params.put("gender", gender);
                params.put("age", dob);
                return params;
            }
        };
        // Adding request to request queue
        AppSingleton.getInstance(getApplicationContext()).addToRequestQueue(strReq, cancel_req_tag);
    }

    private void showDialog() {
        if (!progressDialog.isShowing())
            progressDialog.show();
    }

    private void hideDialog() {
        if (progressDialog.isShowing())
            progressDialog.dismiss();
    }

}
```

UserActivity.java(This is what the activity I should get as soon as i press the login button after entering the credentials, but my app force closes when I press the login button after entering the credentials.,ie.., I am unable to login into the userActivity(NavigationDrawer Activity)

```
package com.androidtutorialpoint.androidlogin;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.view.View;
import android.support.design.widget.NavigationView;
import android.support.v4.view.GravityCompat;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;

public class UserActivity extends AppCompatActivity
        implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_user);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .setAction("Action", null).show();
            }
        });

        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
        drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
        toggle.syncState();

        NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
            drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.user, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        if (id == R.id.nav_camera) {
            // Handle the camera action
        } else if (id == R.id.nav_gallery) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_slideshow) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_manage) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_share) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_send) {

        }

        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        return true;
    }
}
```

Please help me friends, If needed, I can post the xml layout files and logcat too.,

StackTrace:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.androidtutorialpoint.androidlogin/com.androidtutorialpoint.androidlogin.UserActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #17: Binary XML file line #17: Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #17: Binary XML file line #17: Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
                                                                                      Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #17: Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
                                                                                      Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
```

XML layout:
activity_user:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:openDrawer="start"
    tools:context=".UserActivity">

    <include
        layout="@layout/app_bar_user"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_user"
        app:menu="@menu/activity_user_drawer" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.androidtutorialpoint.androidlogin"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.volley:volley:1.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.0.0'

}
```

project build.gradle

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.3'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Styles.xml

```
<resources>

    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    </style>

    <style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    </style>

    <style name="AppTheme.AppBarOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" />

    <style name="AppTheme.PopupOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

</resources>
```

Comment: Yes post stack trace...

Comment: @SouravGanguly I'm umable to post my logcat, Since it's too long.

Comment: You don't have to post entire just post where error started and 5-6 lines below that

Comment: --------- beginning of crash
03-16 18:40:21.640 2558-2558/com.androidtutorialpoint.androidlogin E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: mainProcess: com.androidtutorialpoint.androidlogin, PID: 2558
                                                                                     java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.androidtutorialpoint.androidlogin/com.androidtutorialpoint.androidlogin.UserActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #17: Binary XML file line #17: Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.NavigationView

Comment: post your stack trace in your post....

Comment: @SouravGanguly How can  i do that?

Comment: @SouravGanguly i had added my stackTrace as a edit of this post. Kindly see it and help me now,

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30709419/error-inflating-class-android-support-design-widget-navigationview

Comment: edit your post.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30709419/error-inflating-class-android-support-design-widget-navigationview

Comment: @SouravGanguly i had editted my post, as per the link you send me, Now please check it. Thanks,.

Comment: there is problem in your xml file line number 17