# Navigation drawer without AppCompat theme

Tags: android, xml, navigation-drawer

I am trying to setup navigation drawer "without" AppCompat. I am getting an error `You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with the design library`
Any ideas?

I setup my `styles.xml as:

```
<resources>
    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Material.Light">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    </style>
</resources>
```

and in my AndroidManifest.xml file I have the `android:theme="@style/AppTheme"` only.

My `activity_main.xml` has:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Hello World!" />

    </RelativeLayout>
    <!-- The navigation drawer -->
    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
        app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer" />
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

nav_header_main and activity_main drawer contents are same as from android studio examples and my MainActivity onCreate function is pretty straightforward:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}
```

My build.bradle dependencies are:

```
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v13:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:26.1.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'
}
```

The error is:

```
12-08 15:11:19.095 16936-16936/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                   Process: com.xxx.xxx, PID: 16936
                                                   java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.xxx.xxx/com.xxx.xxx.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #0: Binary XML file line #0: Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2684)
                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2751)
                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1496)
                                                       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6186)
                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:889)
                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:779)
                                                    Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #0: Binary XML file line #0: Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
                                                    Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #0: Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
                                                    Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance0(Native Method)
                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:430)
                                                       at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:645)
                                                       at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:787)
                                                       at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:727)
                                                       at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:858)
                                                       at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:821)
                                                       at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:518)
                                                       at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:426)
                                                       at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:377)
                                                       at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:412)
                                                       at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:2415)
                                                       at com.xxx.xxx.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:24)
                                                       at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6684)
                                                       at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1119)
                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2637)
                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2751)
                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1496)
                                                       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6186)
                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:889)
                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:779)
                                                    Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with the design library.
                                                       at android.support.design.widget.ThemeUtils.checkAppCompatTheme(ThemeUtils.java:33)
                                                       at android.support.design.widget.NavigationView.<init>(NavigationView.java:104)
                                                       at android.support.design.widget.NavigationView.<init>(NavigationView.java:98)
                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance0(Native Method) 
                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:430) 
                                                       at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:645) 
                                                       at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:787) 
                                                       at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:727) 
                                                       at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:858) 
                                                       at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:821) 
                                                       at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:518) 
                                                       at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:426) 
                                                       at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:377) 
                                                       at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:412) 
                                                       at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:2415) 
                                                       at com.xxx.xxx.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:24) 
                                                       at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6684) 
                                                       at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1119) 
                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2637) 
                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2751) 
                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java) 
                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1496) 
                                                       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6186) 
                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:889) 
                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:779)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
implementation 'com.android.support:design:26.1.0'
```

Anything you pull in from this artifact will require `appcompat-v7`, `Theme.AppCompat`, etc. In your case, `NavigationView` is from this library.

I do not have `NavigationView` in [my cross-port of the Design widgets to `Theme.Material`](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-crossport). AFAIK, you will need to drop this widget and use something else for the drawer contents (e.g., `RecyclerView`).

Note that `DrawerLayout` does *not* require `appcompat-v7`, so that part is fine.

Comment: I think you are right. If I switch to `parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar"` in styles.xml then app function but the `ActionBar` is missing. How can I get the `ActionBar` in an activity "easily" ?

Comment: @EvrenYurtesen: Your question is about how *not* to use that theme. If you want to use something based on `Theme.AppCompat`, you need to inherit from `AppCompatActivity`, among other things.

Answer (score 0):

```
<style name="AppTheme.Base" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">

    <item name="colorPrimary">#873AB0</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">#256DA8</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">#11BCD4</item>
    <item name="android:textColorPrimary">#212222</item>
    <item name="android:textColorSecondary">#646464</item>

</style>
```

from above snippet remove

```
        <item name="android:textColorPrimary">#212222</item>
        <item name="android:textColorSecondary">#646464</item>
```

check [Example](https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/Fragment-Navigation-Drawer)

Hope this helps you.

Comment: Are you copy/paste'ing others answers?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30709419/error-inflating-class-android-support-design-widget-navigationview/34511285
In that question the OP is using AppCompat theme...

Comment: Nope it's releevnt to this answer. if it's helps you

Comment: It is not relevant at all, because everything works fine if I switch to an AppCompat theme. For example if I just set `parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar"` in my styles.xml the drawer works fine. Totally irrelevant answers, you should try to understand the question. I am trying to figure out if it is possible to solve the issue without using AppCompat theme. Dont you think I already searched all answers to similar questions at stackoverflow? :) thats how I knew you copy/pasted

Comment: Did uyou seen i'm putting "Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar" there in style. if thsi answer is not gave any help then i'll delete this for sure. waiting for your response.

Comment: The problem is that I want the default action bar and if I put an AppCompat theme it disappears. Even if I select `Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar`

Comment: if you put "Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar" then also got same problem?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/160800/discussion-between-evren-yurtesen-and-insanecat).