# setcontentview(r.layout.activity_main) crash

Tags: android, crash, oncreate, main-activity

My application is closed(crash) and shows on Android monitor error it :
activities.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:77)
what can i do?!

this is my logcat:

```
03-14 10:21:04.255 5003-5003/com.panaceasoft.citiesdirectorySHZ E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                              Process: com.panaceasoft.citiesdirectorySHZ, PID: 5003
                                                                              java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.panaceasoft.citiesdirectorySHZ/com.panaceasoft.citiesdirectorySHZ.activities.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #12: Binary XML file line #12: Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
                                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2665)
                                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2726)
                                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
                                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1477)
                                                                                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119)
                                                                                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886)
                                                                                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
                                                                               Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #12: Binary XML file line #12: Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
                                                                               Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #12: Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
                                                                               Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
                                                                                  at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance0(Native Method)
                                                                                  at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:430)
                                                                                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:645)
                                                                                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:787)
                                                                                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:727)
                                                                                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:858)
                                                                                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:821)
                                                                                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:518)
                                                                                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:426)
                                                                                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:377)
                                                                                  at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:280)
                                                                                  at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140)
                                                                                  at com.panaceasoft.citiesdirectorySHZ.activities.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:77)
                                                                                  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6679)
                                                                                  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1118)
                                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2618)
                                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2726)
                                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
                                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1477)
                                                                                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119)
                                                                                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886)
                                                                                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
                                                                               Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Landroid/support/v7/internal/view/menu/MenuBuilder;
                                                                                  at android.support.design.widget.NavigationView.<init>(NavigationView.java:95)
                                                                                  at android.support.design.widget.NavigationView.<init>(NavigationView.java:88)
                                                                                  at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance0(Native Method) 
                                                                                  at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:430) 
                                                                                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:645) 
                                                                                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:787) 
                                                                                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:727) 
                                                                                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:858) 
                                                                                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:821) 
                                                                                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:518) 
                                                                                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:426) 
                                                                                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:377) 
                                                                                  at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:280) 
                                                                                  at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140) 
                                                                                  at com.panaceasoft.citiesdirectorySHZ.activities.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:77) 
                                                                                  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6679) 
                                                                                  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1118) 
                                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2618) 
                                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2726) 
                                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java) 
                                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1477) 
                                                                                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
                                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119) 
                                                                                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886) 
                                                                                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776) 
03-14 10:21:04.255 5003-5003/com.panaceasoft.citiesdirectorySHZ E/AndroidRuntime: Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "android.support.v7.internal.view.menu.MenuBuilder" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.panaceasoft.citiesdirectorySHZ-1/base.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.panaceasoft.citiesdirectorySHZ-1/split_lib_dependencies_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.panaceasoft.citiesdirectorySHZ-1/split_lib_slice_0_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.panaceasoft.citiesdirectorySHZ-1/split_lib_slice_1_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.panaceasoft.citiesdirectorySHZ-1/split_lib_slice_2_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.panaceasoft.citiesdirectorySHZ-1/split_lib_slice_3_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.panaceasoft.citiesdirectorySHZ-1/split_lib_slice_4_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.panaceasoft.citiesdirectorySHZ-1/split_lib_slice_5_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.panaceasoft.citiesdirectorySHZ-1/split_lib_slice_6_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.panaceasoft.citiesdirectorySHZ-1/split_lib_slice_7_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.panaceasoft.citiesdirectorySHZ-1/split_lib_slice_8_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.panaceasoft.citiesdirectorySHZ-1/split_lib_slice_9_apk.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.panaceasoft.citiesdirectorySHZ-1/lib/x86, /system/lib, /vendor/lib]]
                                                                                      at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
                                                                                      at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:380)
                                                                                      at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
                                                                                        ... 27 more
```

> this is my MainActivity java code:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    initUtils();

    initUI();

    initData();

    bindData();

}
```

> and this is my build.gradle:

```
android {
compileSdkVersion 24
buildToolsVersion '25.0.0'

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.panaceasoft.citiesdirectorySHZ"
    minSdkVersion 10
    targetSdkVersion 22
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}




dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
})
compile files('libs/android-async-http-1.4.4.jar')
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.1'
compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:22.2.1'
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:22.2.1'
compile 'com.android.support:design:22.2.1'
compile 'com.android.support:palette-v7:22.2.1'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:22.2.1'
compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.2.4'
compile 'com.mcxiaoke.volley:library:1.0.+'
compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
compile 'com.pnikosis:materialish-progress:1.5'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.5.0'
compile 'com.afollestad.material-dialogs:core:0.9.0.1'
compile 'com.github.rey5137:material:1.1.1'
compile 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:1.3.0'
compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'

}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/30785292/3364266 check this ans

Comment: the link does not Helpful

Comment: No one to answer ?!
is very important