# Specific Error NavigationView with API 23 android

Tags: java, android, xml, navigation-drawer

When the project runs on an API greater than Android 23, it works fine, but when running on API 23, the following error occurs:

> E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                     Process: faculdade.br.picuma, PID: 8066
>                     java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{faculdade.br.picuma/faculdade.br.picuma.view.PerfilClienteActivity}:
>   android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #35: Binary XML
>   file line #35: Error inflating class
>   android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
>                         at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3319)
>                         at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3415)
>                         at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:229)
>                         at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1821)
>                         at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>                         at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)

The Gadle APP

```
    android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "faculdade.br.picuma"
        minSdkVersion 23
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:27.1.1'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:12.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:12.0.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:27.0.2'
    implementation 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.7.0'
}
```

Main class

```
public class PerfilClienteActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private TabLayout tabLayoutPerfilCliente;
    private ViewPager viewPagerPerfilCliente;
    private CircleImageView circleImageViewClientePerfil;
    private TextView tvNomeClientePerfilCliente;
    private DrawerLayout drawerPerfilCliente;
    private ActionBarDrawerToggle mToggle;
    private NavigationView navigationViewPerfilCliente;
    private Login dadosUsuario;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_perfil_cliente);

        drawerPerfilCliente = findViewById(R.id.drawerPerfilCliente);
        navigationViewPerfilCliente = findViewById(R.id.navigationViewPerfilCliente);

        mToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, drawerPerfilCliente, R.string.opem, R.string.close);
        drawerPerfilCliente.addDrawerListener(mToggle);
        setupDrawerContent(navigationViewPerfilCliente);

        mToggle.syncState();
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

        tabLayoutPerfilCliente = findViewById(R.id.tabLayoutPerfilCliente);
        viewPagerPerfilCliente = findViewById(R.id.viewPagerPerfilCliente);

        viewPagerPerfilCliente.setAdapter(new AdapterGerenciadorFragmentPerfilCliente(getSupportFragmentManager(), getResources().getStringArray(R.array.title_tab_perfil_cliente)));
        tabLayoutPerfilCliente.setupWithViewPager(viewPagerPerfilCliente);

        circleImageViewClientePerfil = findViewById(R.id.circleImageViewClientePerfil);
        tvNomeClientePerfilCliente = findViewById(R.id.tvNomeClientePerfilCliente);

        Intent intent = getIntent();

        if (intent.getBooleanExtra("dados", false)) {

            this.setarDadosCliente(intent.getStringExtra("dados_usuario"));

        }

    }

[...]

}
```

Main xml

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".view.PerfilClienteActivity"
    android:id="@+id/drawerPerfilCliente">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/llCorpoPerfilCliente"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@color/colorAccent">

            <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
                android:id="@+id/tabLayoutPerfilCliente"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:tabIndicatorColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
                app:tabSelectedTextColor="@color/preto"></android.support.design.widget.TabLayout>

        </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

        <include layout="@layout/content_perfil_cliente"></include>

    </LinearLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/navigationViewPerfilCliente"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_perfil_cliente"
        app:elevation="5dp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/darkGrey"
        app:itemTextColor="@color/preto"
        app:itemIconTint="@color/preto"
        app:menu="@menu/menu_drawer_perfil_cliente"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        >
    </android.support.design.widget.NavigationView>
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Comment: is there a folder name drawable-v21 or values-v21?

Comment: Looking at your gradle file you have `implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:27.0.2` should that be `implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:27.1.1` ? I don't think that is your issue, but I'm surprised you haven't gotten a warning.

Comment: I have not really received any kind of warning regarding the `implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:27.0.2`, I will change to see if it has any effect on the project.

Comment: @Sam. I have drawable and dawable-v24 (where are my icons) and no values-21.

Comment: @Barns 
There was no effect on the project's change in glade.

Comment: put the xml file in both.. have a look at these answers https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30709419/error-inflating-class-android-support-design-widget-navigationview

Comment: @ Sam I put the xml files in both folders `Drawable` worked perfectly, thank you very much