# java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo_Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.NavigationView

Tags: android, android-layout, gradle, build.gradle, navigationview

I tried to make a navigation view from tutorials video but just me have faced with this error :

```
 android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #17: Binary XML file line #17: Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
```

i tried every solution in git hub & StavkOverFlow like this solution but doesn't worked  :
[Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.NavigationView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30709419/error-inflating-class-android-support-design-widget-navigationview)

and this link :
[Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.NavigationView #1](https://github.com/Marketcloud/marketcloud-sample-android-application/issues/1)

**toolbar.java**

```
    android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar toolbar;
    DrawerLayout drawerLayout;
    NavigationView navigationView;
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        setTheme(R.style.ToolBarTheme); // (for Custom theme)
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        this.setContentView(R.layout.navigation_drawer);
        toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        drawerLayout = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        navigationView = findViewById(R.id.navigation_view);

        ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, drawerLayout, toolbar, R.string.open_drawer, R.string.close_drawer);
        drawerLayout.setDrawerListener(toggle);

        toggle.syncState();

**Activitytoolbar.xml**

    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".ToolBar">


    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">



    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>


</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

**navigation_header.xml**

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="106dp"
    android:padding="60dp"
    android:gravity="bottom"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark"
    android:background="@drawable/pic">

    <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView
        android:layout_width="56dp"
        android:layout_height="56dp"
        android:src="@drawable/woman"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:contentDescription="@string/woman"/>

    <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/sara_lance"
        android:paddingTop="8dp"
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Body1"/>

    <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/saralancer_gmail_com"
        android:paddingTop="4dp"/>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

**navigation_menu.xml**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <group android:checkableBehavior="single">

        <item
            android:title="@string/Inbox"
            android:id="@+id/inbox_id"
            android:icon="@drawable/inbox">

        </item>

        <item
            android:title="@string/Starred"
            android:id="@+id/starred"
            android:icon="@drawable/star">

        </item>

        <item
            android:title="@string/send_mail"
            android:id="@+id/send_mail"
            android:icon="@drawable/send">

        </item>

        <item
            android:title="@string/drafts"
            android:id="@+id/drafts"
            android:icon="@drawable/drafts">

        </item>


    </group>

    <item
        android:title="@string/subheader">
        <menu>

            <item
                android:title="@string/all_mail"
                android:id="@+id/all_mail"
                android:icon="@drawable/email">

            </item>

            <item
                android:title="@string/trash"
                android:id="@+id/trash"
                android:icon="@drawable/trash">

            </item>

            <item
                android:title="@string/spam"
                android:id="@+id/spam"
                android:icon="@drawable/spam">


            </item>


        </menu>
    </item>

</menu>
```

and my
**Build.gradle**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "ir.aliakhtari.materialdesignfirst"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0-alpha1'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.2'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0-alpha1'
}
```

**My Logcat**

```
 --------- beginning of crash
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: ir.aliakhtari.materialdesignfirst, PID: 739
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{ir.aliakhtari.materialdesignfirst/ir.aliakhtari.materialdesignfirst.ToolBar}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #17: Binary XML file line #17: Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2665)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2726)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1477)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #17: Binary XML file line #17: Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #17: Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
     Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:430)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:645)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:787)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:727)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:858)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:821)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:518)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:426)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:377)
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:287)
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:139)
        at ir.aliakhtari.materialdesignfirst.ToolBar.onCreate(ToolBar.java:25)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6679)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1118)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2618)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2726)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1477)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #11: Binary XML file line #11: Error inflating class android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #11: Error inflating class android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView
     Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:430)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:645)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:787)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:727)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:858)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:821)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:518)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:426)
        at android.support.design.internal.NavigationMenuPresenter.inflateHeaderView(NavigationMenuPresenter.java:200)
        at android.support.design.widget.NavigationView.inflateHeaderView(NavigationView.java:277)
        at android.support.design.widget.NavigationView.<init>(NavigationView.java:189)
        at android.support.design.widget.NavigationView.<init>(NavigationView.java:100)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:430)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:645)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:787)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:727)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:858)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:821)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:518)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:426)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:377)
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:287)
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:139)
        at ir.aliakhtari.materialdesignfirst.ToolBar.onCreate(ToolBar.java:25)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6679)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1118)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2618)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2726)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1477)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
     Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a 478338012 byte allocation with 4194304 free bytes and 77MB until OOM
        at dalvik.system.VMRuntime.newNonMovableArray(Native Method)
        at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeAsset(Native Method)
        at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:620)
        at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream(BitmapFactory.java:455)
        at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromResourceStream(Drawable.java:1155)
        at android.content.res.ResourcesImpl.loadDrawableForCookie(ResourcesImpl.java:720)
        at android.content.res.ResourcesImpl.loadDrawable(ResourcesImpl.java:571)
        at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:858)
        at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:928)
        at android.widget.ImageView.<init>(ImageView.java:162)
        at android.widget.ImageView.<init>(ImageView.java:150)
        at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView.<init>(AppCompatImageView.java:71)
        at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView.<init>(AppCompatImageView.java:67)
            ... 38 more
```

as i know this error when happen that appcompat and library and design support library doesn't match. But When i change the version, i still faced to the new error.

**In Addision, I'm sorry for writing mistakes in my question.**

now what should i do to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

One of your drawables is too large. I think it's `@drawable/woman`.

You have

> OutOfMemoryError

when trying to compress it into 56dp field. Also in `API 28` all icons must be in XML adoptable format. Check this too, and I recommend you use `app:srcCompat` instead of `android:src`.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please proofread and properly format your posts. Thanks!

Comment: No I checked and even that i change my drawable image, it doesn’t affect .