# Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #16: Error inflating class com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView

Tags: java, android, material-design, navigationview, androidx

My app is using the new AndroidX framework, and when setting up a `com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView` (in my activity_main.xml file), I got this error:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.gaucow.betterbartersystem/com.gaucow.betterbartersystem.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #16: Binary XML file line #16: Error inflating class com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2947)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3008)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap14(ActivityThread.java)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1650)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6688)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1468)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1358)
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #16: Binary XML file line #16: Error inflating class com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #16: Error inflating class com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
     Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:430)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:652)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:794)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:734)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:865)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:828)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:525)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:427)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:378)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:469)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140)
        at com.gaucow.betterbartersystem.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:38)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6912)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1126)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2900)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3008)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap14(ActivityThread.java)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1650)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6688)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1468)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1358)
     Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x0
        at android.content.res.ResourcesImpl.getValue(ResourcesImpl.java:202)
        at android.content.res.Resources.getColorStateList(Resources.java:1861)
        at android.content.Context.getColorStateList(Context.java:542)
        at androidx.appcompat.content.res.AppCompatResources.getColorStateList(AppCompatResources.java:67)
        at com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView.createDefaultColorStateList(NavigationView.java:513)
        at com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView.<init>(NavigationView.java:153)
        at com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView.<init>(NavigationView.java:104)
```

My code is here: https://github.com/GauthamRajesh/BetterBarterSystem

Thanks for helping me solve this problem!

PS: I have looked at the possible duplicate question, and the answer for that involves the `android.support` library. However, since I am not using the support or design libraries in my code, the solution doesn't apply to me. The `android.support` version of `NavigationView` and the Android material version of `NavigationView` are different.

I tried using this link to help as well, but I couldn't find the answer: https://material.io/develop/android/components/navigation-view/

Comment: You forgot to add  dependencies  for `NavigationView`   `implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.1'`

Comment: @Nilesh He's already added that library `implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0-rc02'`

Comment: @Bek its same issue Check the exception  `Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x0`

Comment: its a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30709419/error-inflating-class-android-support-design-widget-navigationview

Comment: @NileshRathod the answer says that the support and appcompat libraries should be the same. In my case, the material library and the androidx library are the same version, so the solution doesn't apply.

Comment: @GauthamRajesh the problem is not of lib the pro is here Check the exception `Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x0`

Comment: Somehow your theme is causing the problem. Use `Theme.AppCompat` instead of `Theme.MaterialComponents` and change style accordingly.

Comment: Android studio reporting wrong crash. I tested and it's working.

Comment: @Nilesh the problem was related to Theme and android studio was reporting wrong crash.

Comment: @Bek I changed my `NewMaterialTheme` to inherit from `Theme.AppCompat` and I still get the same error.

Comment: can you post your style and manifest xml.

Comment: or update project on the github

Comment: @Bek I updated the project on github

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your style as below

```
<style name="AppBarOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" />
<style name="PopupOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />
<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>

<style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
</style>
```

Change your manifest to

```
 <application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name_real"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
    tools:ignore="GoogleAppIndexingWarning">
    <activity android:name=".SignIn" android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_main"/>
</application>
```

Comment: I got the same error, but this time for inflating the `MaterialButton`: 
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.gaucow.betterbartersystem/com.gaucow.betterbartersystem.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #10: Binary XML file line #10: Error inflating class com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton

Comment: which version of `android studio` are you using?

Comment: I uploaded project to github https://github.com/droidapp/BetterBarterSystem. Clone it. If it doesn't work then, there's a problem with your IDE. Now even if I change style to previews version it's working correctly.

Comment: Happy to help you.

Answer (score 3):

Try delete all large image (background, icon, ...) in nav_header_main.xml file!