# Error inflating class android.support.design.internal.NavigationMenuItemView

Tags: java, android, xml

I am running this app on sdk version 28. The problem `android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #17: Binary XML file line #17: Error inflating class android.support.design.internal.NavigationMenuItemView`
 suddenly appeared, causing my app to crash. After checking the nav drawer I know that the problem is when there are menu items to inflate, because when I comment them out the app runs with no problems, i also checked if the problem is with the drawables but I changed them with no effect.

here are my files

1. manifest.xml file

   ```
   <application
       android:allowBackup="true"
       android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
       android:label="@string/app_name"
       android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
       android:supportsRtl="true"
       android:theme="@style/SemiGofaaTheme">
       <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
           <intent-filter>
               <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

               <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
           </intent-filter>
       </activity>


   </application>
   ```
2. styles.xml

   ```
   <!-- Base application theme. -->
   <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
       <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
       <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
       <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
       <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
   </style>
   <!-- SemiGofaa application theme. -->
   <style name="SemiGofaaTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">
       <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
       <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
       <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
       <item name="android:windowDrawsSystemBarBackgrounds">true</item>
       <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
       <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
       <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
       <item name="android:colorBackground">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
       <item name="fontFamily">@font/cairo</item>
       <item name="android:statusBarColor">@color/colorAccent</item>
       <item name="alertDialogTheme">@style/AlertDialog.AppCompat.Light</item>
       <item name="android:windowContentTransitions">true</item>
       <!--<item name="android:background">@drawable/bkg</item>-->
   </style>

   <style name="SemiGofaaTheme.AppBarOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" />

   <style name="SemiGofaaTheme.PopupOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

   <style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
       <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
       <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
   </style>

   <style name="AppTheme.AppBarOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" />

   <style name="AppTheme.PopupOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />
   ```
3. build.gradle:

   ```
   android {
       compileSdkVersion 28
       defaultConfig {
           applicationId "semicode.semigofaa"
           minSdkVersion 21
           targetSdkVersion 28
           versionCode 5
           versionName "0.5"
           testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
       }
       buildTypes {
           release {
               minifyEnabled false
               proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
           }
       }
       lintOptions {
           checkReleaseBuilds false
           // Or, if you prefer, you can continue to check for errors in release builds,
           // but continue the build even when errors are found:
           abortOnError false
       }
   ```
4. MainActivity.java

   ```
   public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

   @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

       Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
       setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

       DrawerLayout drawer = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
       ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
               this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
       drawer.addDrawerListener(toggle);
       toggle.syncState();
       NavigationView navigationView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
       navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
   }

   @SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
   @Override
   public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
       // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
       int id = item.getItemId();

       if (id == R.id.nav_gofaas) {
           if(userLoggedIn)
               startActivity(new Intent(this, GofaasActivity.class));
           else
               startActivity(new Intent(this, LoginActivity.class));
       } else if (id == R.id.nav_wishlist) {
           if(userLoggedIn)
               startActivity(new Intent(this, WishlistActivity.class));
           else
               startActivity(new Intent(this, LoginActivity.class));
       } else if (id == R.id.nav_settings) {

       } else if (id == R.id.nav_terms) {
           startActivity(new Intent(this,TermsActivity.class));
       } else if (id == R.id.nav_contact_us) {

       }else if (id == R.id.nav_about) {
           startActivity(new Intent(this,AboutActivity.class));
       } else if (id == R.id.nav_share) {
           Intent sendIntent = new Intent();
           sendIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
           sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,getString(R.string.hey_check_out_semigofaa_app) + link);
           sendIntent.setType("text/plain");
           startActivity(sendIntent);
       }else if(id == R.id.log_out_nav_drawer){
           SaveAppData.clearUserData(this);
           SaveSharedPreference.clearUserData(this);
           startActivity(new Intent(this,MainActivity.class));
           finish();
           Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Logged out",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
       }

       DrawerLayout drawer = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
       drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
       return true;
   }
   ```

   }

Comment: where is your layout file? and full gradle build

Comment: Have you tried the answers outlined here? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30709419/error-inflating-class-android-support-design-widget-navigationview

Answer (score 0):

attaching menu at navigationview

```
<

android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
            android:id="@+id/nav_view"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="start"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:headerLayout="@layout/header"
            app:menu="@menu/menu_items"
```

/>

and make separate file for menu like

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<item android:id="@+id/mhome" android:title="HOME"
    android:icon="@drawable/homeicon"
    android:checkable="true"></item>
<item android:id="@+id/mportfolio" android:title="PORLFOLIO"
    android:icon="@drawable/portfolioicon"
    android:checkable="true"></item>
<item android:id="@+id/mcareer" android:title="CAREER"
    android:icon="@drawable/careericon"
    android:checkable="true"></item>
<item android:id="@+id/mblog" android:title="BLOG"
    android:icon="@drawable/blogicon"
    android:checkable="true"></item>

</menu>
```