# how fix Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.NavigationView

Tags: java, android, androidx, android-navigationview, material-components-android

I have problem and I can't find the solution !
I use in XML :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

    <androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout
      xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
      xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
      android:id="@+id/activity_main"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      tools:context="com.example.libraryproject.MainActivity"
      android:background="@android:color/holo_green_dark">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">


        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Main"
            android:textSize="50dp"
            android:id="@+id/textView"
            android:layout_marginTop="200dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="130dp"/>


    </RelativeLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView ------! #32
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:menu="@menu/navigation_menu"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/navigation_header"
        android:id="@+id/nv">
    </android.support.design.widget.NavigationView>

</androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

And the error show is :
android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #32: Binary XML file line #32: Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.NavigationView

in app :
[image: APP PAGE]

Comment: You have the same error explained here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30709419/error-inflating-class-android-support-design-widget-navigationview

Comment: You are using androidx. Use the `com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In your `build.gradle` there are **some errors**:

- the support libraries 29.0.2 and 29.1.1 **don't exist**
- you are using **androidx and support libraries together** and **you can't** do it.

Then, since you are using the androidx component `<androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout` you have to use the

```
<com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
 ...>
```

instead of `android.support.design.widget.NavigationView`.

Finally check your App theme. You **have to use a [Material Component Theme](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/master/docs/getting-started.md#4-change-your-app-theme-to-inherit-from-a-material-components-theme)**.

Answer (score 4):

Replace `android.support.design.widget.NavigationView` with `com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView` because you are using AndroidX.