# Error inflating NavigationDrawer android

Tags: android, android-activity, navigation-drawer, android-navigationview

My app shows the following error.

```
Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
```

For all lollipop mobiles, it works fine.. But it crashes on versions lower than lollipop.

I tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30547323/error-when-using-any-android-design-support-library-elements) but it didn't help.

Below is my build.gradle

```
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
    apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
    android {
    compileSdkVersion 22
    buildToolsVersion "22.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "app.aguai.medieazy"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 22
        versionCode 21
        versionName "2.0"
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }

    }
    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/license.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/notice.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/ASL2.0'
    }
}


   dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile files('libs/httpclient-4.3.6.jar')
    compile files('libs/achartengine-1.0.0.jar')
    compile files('libs/httpcore-4.3.3.jar')
    compile files('libs/httpmime-4.3.6.jar')
    compile files('libs/FlurryAnalytics-5.5.0.jar')
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.1'
    compile 'cn.pedant.sweetalert:library:1.3'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:22.2.1'
    compile 'com.rengwuxian.materialedittext:library:2.1.4'
    compile 'it.neokree:MaterialTabs:0.11'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.1.0'
    compile 'com.oguzdev:CircularFloatingActionMenu:1.0.2'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:22.2.1'
    compile 'com.github.blackfizz:eazegraph:1.2.5l@aar'
    compile 'com.nineoldandroids:library:2.4.0'
   }
```

My navigation drawer xml:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:openDrawer="start">

    <include
        layout="@layout/app_bar_home_nav"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_home_nav"
        app:menu="@menu/activity_home_nav_drawer" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

My navigation header:

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/nav_header_height"
    android:background="#2793b0"
    android:gravity="bottom"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/nav_dp"
        android:layout_width="75dp"
        android:layout_height="75dp"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/nav_header_vertical_spacing"
        android:src="@android:drawable/sym_def_app_icon" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/nav_header_vertical_spacing"
        android:text="Android Studio"
        android:id="@+id/navName" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/navNumber"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="android.studio@android.com" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Please help, becasue of this only, I am having problems in code.
Thanx in advance.

My full stacktrace:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{app.aguai.medieazy/app.aguai.medieazy.activities.Home}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #16: Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2200)
                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2249)
                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:141)
                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1212)
                                                                        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5052)
                                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:609)
                                                                        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
                                                                     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #16: Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
                                                                        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:623)
                                                                        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:699)
                                                                        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:758)
                                                                        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:495)
                                                                        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:400)
                                                                        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353)
                                                                        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:249)
                                                                        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:106)
                                                                        at app.aguai.medieazy.activities.Home.onCreate(Home.java:40)
                                                                        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5248)
                                                                        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2164)
                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2249) 
                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:141) 
                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1212) 
                                                                        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136) 
                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5052) 
                                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
                                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793) 
                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:609) 
                                                                        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 
                                                                     Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
                                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
                                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
                                                                        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:597)
                                                                        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:699) 
                                                                        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:758) 
                                                                        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:495) 
                                                                        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:400) 
                                                                        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353) 
                                                                        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:249) 
                                                                        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:106) 
                                                                        at app.aguai.medieazy.activities.Home.onCreate(Home.java:40) 
                                                                        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5248) 
                                                                        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087) 
                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2164) 
                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2249) 
                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:141) 
                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1212) 
                                                                        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136) 
                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5052) 
                                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
                                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793) 
                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:609) 
                                                                        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 
                                                                     Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x7f0200b3
                                                                        at android.content.res.Resources.getValue(Resources.java:1133)
                                                                        at android.content.res.MiuiResources.getValue(MiuiResources.java:124)
                                                                        at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable(Resources.java:708)
                                                                        at android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat.getDrawable(ContextCompat.java:321)
                                                                        at android.support.v7.internal.widget.TintManager.getDrawable(TintManager.java:145)
                                                                        at android.support.v7.internal.view.menu.MenuItemImpl.getIcon(MenuItemImpl.java:422)
                                                                        at android.support.design.internal.NavigationMenuPresenter$NavigationMenuAdapter.prepareMenuItems(NavigationMenuPresenter.java:393)
                                                                        at android.support.design.internal.NavigationMenuPresenter$NavigationMenuAdapter.<init>(NavigationMenuPresenter.java:255)
                                                                        at android.support.design.internal.NavigationMenuPresenter.getMenuView(NavigationMenuPresenter.java:97)
                                                                        at android.support.design.widget.NavigationView.<init>(NavigationView.java:149)
                                                                        at android.support.design.widget.NavigationView.<init>(NavigationView.java:88)
                                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method) 
                                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423) 
                                                                        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:597) 
                                                                        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:699) 
                                                                        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:758) 
                                                                        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:495) 
                                                                        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:400) 
                                                                        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353) 
                                                                        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:249) 
                                                                        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:106) 
                                                                        at app.aguai.medieazy.activities.Home.onCreate(Home.java:40) 
                                                                        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5248) 
                                                                        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087) 
                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2164) 
                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2249) 
                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:141) 
                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1212) 
                                                                        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136) 
                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5052) 
                                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
                                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793) 
                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:609) 
                                                                        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it by changing the path of the icons.
The icons were in drawable(v21), I moved them to "drawable" and it worked,
Somehow drawable

Answer (score 0):

Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x7f0200b3

you are using some drawable in your code which does not exist in your project. Replace it with a valid drawable

Comment: but it should not even compile if the resources are not present right?

Comment: I am not sure about this but sometimes this happens. So just check your code you might be using some drawable in xml or java code.

Comment: I think the problem is due to   android:src="@android:drawable/sym_def_app_icon", change the image and run again

Comment: I tried even removing the imageview, it is not working

Comment: you might be doing this in your activity class while implementing drawertoggle.

Answer (score 0):

I had the similar issue. checked the navigationview by removing

```
app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"

app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer
```

these two line separately and check the android monitor for errors

```
<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
android:id="@+id/nav_view"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_gravity="start"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer"
/>
```

removing app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main" doesn't make any changes gives me the same error

But after removing app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer" app works fine and load the left side navigation with no menu item. so as you can see in my error list it says Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x7f020052

So I checked by removing custom vector icons in menu item I placed in my activity_main_drawer in res->menu . Its now working fine. problem with a one icon res file.