# Error inflating FloatingActionButton with API 16

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I was working on my application only with API 22 & 23.
I had just test my application with API 16, it's crash and the console give me this error: 
**Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton**

I had searched a lot about this error and i found nothing to fix mine.

I am using "Theme.AppCompat" in my style.xml (for each different theme). My app is compiled with SDK 23, minSdkVersion is 16 and targetSdkVersion is 23.

this is my log

```
com.ddesign.foyer E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                             java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.ddesign.foyer/com.ddesign.foyer.item.ItemListActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #19: Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2059)
                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2084)
                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:130)
                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1195)
                                                                 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
                                                                 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
                                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
                                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
                                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
                                                                 at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
                                                              Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #19: Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
                                                                 at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:613)
                                                                 at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:687)
                                                                 at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:746)
                                                                 at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489)
                                                                 at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
                                                                 at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352)
                                                                 at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:255)
                                                                 at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:109)
                                                                 at com.ddesign.foyer.item.ItemListActivity.onCreate(ItemListActivity.java:109)
                                                                 at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5008)
                                                                 at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1079)
                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2023)
                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2084) 
                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:130) 
                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1195) 
                                                                 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
                                                                 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137) 
                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745) 
                                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
                                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511) 
                                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786) 
                                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553) 
                                                                 at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 
                                                              Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
                                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
                                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:417)
                                                                 at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:587)
                                                                 at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:687) 
                                                                 at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:746) 
                                                                 at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489) 
                                                                 at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396) 
                                                                 at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352) 
                                                                 at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:255) 
                                                                 at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:109) 
                                                                 at com.ddesign.foyer.item.ItemListActivity.onCreate(ItemListActivity.java:109) 
                                                                 at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5008) 
                                                                 at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1079) 
                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2023) 
                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2084) 
                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:130) 
                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1195) 
                                                                 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
                                                                 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137) 
                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745) 
                                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
                                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511) 
                                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786) 
                                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553) 
                                                                 at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 
                                                              Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: File res/drawable/cart.xml from drawable resource ID #0x7f02003f
                                                                 at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:1923)
                                                                 at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:601)
                                                                 at android.widget.ImageView.<init>(ImageView.java:120)
                                                                 at android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton.<init>(FloatingActionButton.java:83)
                                                                 at android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton.<init>(FloatingActionButton.java:79)
                                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method) 
                                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:417) 
                                                                 at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:587) 
                                                                 at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:687) 
                                                                 at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:746) 
                                                                 at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489) 
                                                                 at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396) 
                                                                 at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352) 
                                                                 at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:255) 
                                                                 at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:109) 
                                                                 at com.ddesign.foyer.item.ItemListActivity.onCreate(ItemListActivity.java:109) 
                                                                 at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5008) 
                                                                 at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1079) 
                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2023) 
                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2084) 
                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:130) 
                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1195) 
                                                                 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
                                                                 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137) 
                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745) 
                                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
                                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511) 
                                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786) 
                                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553) 
                                                                 at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 
                                                              Caused by: org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException: Binary XML file line #2: invalid drawable tag vector
                                                                 at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXmlInner(Drawable.java:877)
                                                                 at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXml(Drawable.java:818)
                                                                 at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:1920)
                                                                 at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:601) 
                                                                 at android.widget.ImageView.<init>(ImageView.java:120) 
                                                                 at android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton.<init>(FloatingActionButton.java:83) 
                                                                 at android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton.<init>(FloatingActionButton.java:79) 
                                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method) 
                                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:417) 
                                                                 at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:587) 
                                                                 at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:687) 
                                                                 at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:746) 
                                                                 at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489) 
                                                                 at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396) 
                                                                 at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352) 
                                                                 at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:255) 
                                                                 at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:109) 
                                                                 at com.ddesign.foyer.item.ItemListActivity.onCreate(ItemListActivity.java:109) 
                                                                 at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5008) 
                                                                 at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1079) 
                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2023) 
                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2084) 
                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:130) 
                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1195) 
                                                                 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
                                                                 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137) 
                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745) 
                                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
                                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511) 
                                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786) 
                                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553) 
                                                                 at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

I hope you can help me to fix this error.
Thank you for reading me (and my bad english ^^).

EDIT:

(cart.xml)

Comment: No I don't (all is for sdk 23), I change that right now

Comment: Sorry I have: compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.0.1'

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30547323/error-when-using-any-android-design-support-library-elements

Comment: did you read all the way to that part `invalid drawable tag vector`?

Comment: ok I use a svg in cart.xml (can't add by editing my post Oo) I upload it right now, but it work with api 21 and 22 :/

Comment: Use `code` for adding the codes in the above of the editor, perhaps you missed something, anyways, try to use `compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'`

Comment: OK it is cart.xml that cause the error, I will fix it myself, thank you all for your time ! :)